# What is the best way to generate ranks in MYSQL?

Tags: sql, mysql

What's the best way to get the rank of the rows in addition to the row data in MYSQL?

For instance, say I have a list of students and I want to rank on the GPA. I know I can order by the GPA, but what's the quickest way to have MYSQL return the rank as well in the rowdata I get back?

Comment: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/13703/get-the-rank-of-a-user-in-a-score-table

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Get row number on select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will return the rank as `rownum`

```
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 rownum, 
       t.* 
  FROM (SELECT @rownum:=0) r, 
       (SELECT * FROM students ORDER BY gpa DESC) t;
```

Comment: Yours looks much more complicated than William's answer. What's the difference?

Comment: It's a single statement. William's are two separate statements. That's the reason it's more complicated.

Answer (score 6):

This will return the students' rank, student ID, and GPA.

```
set @rownum := 0;
SELECT @rownum := @rownum + 1 AS rank, student_id, gpa 
    FROM `students` ORDER BY gpa DESC
```