# How can generate rounds of permute

Tags: php, algorithm, permute

I want to build a soccer game and I must generate all rounds between teams.
Then I have an array like this

```
$array = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

How can generate all permute between elements without repetitions.

```
array(1,2)
array(3,4)
array(5,6)
array(7,8)
```

Next iteration

```
array(1,3)
array(2,4)
array(5,7)
array(6,8)
```

With normal permutations receive duplicates like this

```
(1 2) (3 4) (5 6) (7 8)
(2 1) (3 4) (5 6) (7 8)
```

3 and 4 were already in the previous round. The same 5 to 6 and 7 to 8.

Comment: Do you need an algorithm that creates permutation of arrays as per your conditions ?

Comment: 8 teams (`team#0`..`team#7`), 7 days (`day#1`..`day#7`).  `team#A` is playing with `team#B` on `day#D` if `A xor B = D`

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff That's brilliant. Do an answer.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff However, only works for powers of 2.

Comment: Isn't (1,2) the same as (2,1)?  That is, teams 1 and 2 are playing each other in both cases?

Comment: It allowed if the order is reversed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I generate a round robin tournament in PHP and MySQL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/658727/how-can-i-generate-a-round-robin-tournament-in-php-and-mysql)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament#Scheduling_algorithm might be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness (on SO), here is the code posted from [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5485965/584846) (thanks to m69's comment above):

```
/****************************************************************************** 
 * Round Robin Pairing Generator 
 * Author: Eugene Wee 
 * Date: 23 May 2005 
 * Last updated: 13 May 2007 
 * Based on an algorithm by Tibor Simko. 
 * 
 * Copyright (c) 2005, 2007 Eugene Wee 
 * 
 * Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person obtaining a copy 
 * of this software and associated documentation files (the "Software"), to deal 
 * in the Software without restriction, including without limitation the rights 
 * to use, copy, modify, merge, publish, distribute, sublicense, and/or sell 
 * copies of the Software, and to permit persons to whom the Software is 
 * furnished to do so, subject to the following conditions: 
 * 
 * The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in 
 * all copies or substantial portions of the Software. 
 * 
 * THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS", WITHOUT WARRANTY OF ANY KIND, EXPRESS OR 
 * IMPLIED, INCLUDING BUT NOT LIMITED TO THE WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY, 
 * FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE AND NONINFRINGEMENT. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE 
 * AUTHORS OR COPYRIGHT HOLDERS BE LIABLE FOR ANY CLAIM, DAMAGES OR OTHER 
 * LIABILITY, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, TORT OR OTHERWISE, ARISING FROM, 
 * OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE SOFTWARE OR THE USE OR OTHER DEALINGS IN 
 * THE SOFTWARE. 
 ******************************************************************************/ 

function generateRoundRobinPairings($num_players) { 
    // Do we have a positive number of players? If not, default to 4. 
    $num_players = ($num_players > 0) ? (int)$num_players : 4; 

    // If necessary, round up number of players to nearest even number. 
    $num_players += $num_players % 2; 

    // Format for pretty alignment of pairings across rounds. 
    $format = "%0" . ceil(log10($num_players)) . "d"; 
    $pairing = "$format-$format "; 

    // Set the return value 
    $ret = $num_players . " Player Round Robin:\n-----------------------"; 

    // Generate the pairings for each round. 
    for ($round = 1; $round < $num_players; $round++) { 
        $ret .= sprintf("\nRound #$format : ", $round); 
        $players_done = array(); 

        // Pair each player except the last. 
        for ($player = 1; $player < $num_players; $player++) { 
            if (!in_array($player, $players_done)) { 
                // Select opponent. 
                $opponent = $round - $player; 
                $opponent += ($opponent < 0) ? $num_players : 1; 

                // Ensure opponent is not the current player. 
                if ($opponent != $player) { 
                    // Choose colours. 
                    if (($player + $opponent) % 2 == 0 xor $player < $opponent) { 
                        // Player plays white. 
                        $ret .= sprintf($pairing, $player, $opponent); 
                    } else { 
                        // Player plays black. 
                        $ret .= sprintf($pairing, $opponent, $player); 
                    } 

                    // This pair of players are done for this round. 
                    $players_done[] = $player; 
                    $players_done[] = $opponent; 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        // Pair the last player. 
        if ($round % 2 == 0) { 
            $opponent = ($round + $num_players) / 2; 
            // Last player plays white. 
            $ret .= sprintf($pairing, $num_players, $opponent); 
        } else { 
            $opponent = ($round + 1) / 2; 
            // Last player plays black. 
            $ret .= sprintf($pairing, $opponent, $num_players); 
        } 
    } 

    return $ret; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I use array_filter to weed out the repeats and the case where teams would play themselves.

```
<?php
$teams = range(1,8);

$match_permutations = array();

foreach($teams as $team1) {
    foreach($teams as $team2) {
        $match_permutations[] = array($team1, $team2);
    }
}

//var_dump($match_permutations);

$match_combinations = array_filter($match_permutations, 
    function($item) {
        if($item[0] < $item[1]) return true;
    }
);

var_dump($match_combinations);
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35453060/3392762 for why this works.

Comment: Dare one ask, why the down vote?

Answer (score -1):

If we had four teams we could write out all possible match permutations like this:

```
(1, 1) (1, 2) (1, 3) (1, 4) 
(2, 1) (2, 2) (2, 3) (2, 4) 
(3, 1) (3, 2) (3, 3) (3, 4) 
(4, 1) (4, 2) (4, 3) (4, 4)
```

You can see the repeats mirrored in the diagonal.

I used the following code to output the above:

```
for($i=1; $i<5; $i++) {
    for($j=1; $j<5; $j++) {
        echo "($i, $j) ";
    }
    echo "\n";
}
```

If we only care about the couplets where $i is less than $j.  Or alternatively where $i is greater than $j, we weed out the duplicates, and the diagonal itself (where the teams play themselves).

```
function team_combinations($no_teams) {
    $combinations = array();
    for($i=1; $i<=$no_teams; $i++) {
        for($j=1; $j<=$no_teams; $j++) {
            if($i < $j)
                $combinations[] = array($i, $j);
        }
    }

    return $combinations;
}

var_export(team_combinations(4));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 3,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    0 => 1,
    1 => 4,
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 3,
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    0 => 2,
    1 => 4,
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    0 => 3,
    1 => 4,
  ),
)
```