# mysql PDO SET statement encounter errors

Tags: php, mysql, database, pdo

I was looking for something that is related to a mysql query and I stumbled to this link [mysql variable usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql) and saw the stored proc-like variable setting. I've tried it in phpmyadmin :

SET @value = 5;
SELECT @rank;

and it is working, but when I tried to place it in PDO statements, it does not work.

```
    $value = "SET @value = 0";
    $stmt = $this->_dbHandle->prepare($value);
    $stmt->execute();
```

Kindly guide on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, my test environment is using sqlite. I've run my query in a test browser rather than in a phpunit test fixture and it did work.sorry guys, miss leaded by the test environment.