# How to get TOP 10 tags associated with a rankable data model? -- Advanced MySQL or ActiveRecord Query problem

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, greatest-n-per-group

Ive run into a stumbling block with an advanced ActiveRecord and/or SQL querying that has to do with tags, ranking, you name it. I hope you MySQL or Rails 3 gurus can help me solve it.

I apologize for a long post in advance :)

First here is a snippet describing my data model

### Data Model

**AggregateData** -- model contains a set of data attributes(**provider_datas**) that come from different data providers and has a calculated **score** attribute used for ranking

```
class AggregateData < ActiveRecord::Base
  # has a pre-populated integer attribute 'score'
  has_many :provider_datas

  # find profiles with top 10 score for specified tag      
  # this is mainly used to determine top 10 scores for later comparison
  # Since this is grouped by score, the actual number of profiles 
  # that have these score may be larger
  def self.find_top_10_by_tag(tag)
    joins(:provider_data_tags)                          \
    .where(:provider_data_tags=>{:tag_id => tag.id})    \
    .group('aggregate_data.score')                      \
    .order('aggregate_data.score DESC')                 \
    .limit(10)
  end

  # simple ranking algorithm, 
  # tells you how many AggregateDatas have better score than this one
  def ranking
    self.connection.select_value("SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS ranking \
      FROM aggregate_datas              \
      WHERE aggregate_datas.score > \
      (SELECT aggregate_datas.score FROM aggregate_data         \
        WHERE aggregate_datas.id = #{self.id})").to_i
  end
end
```

**ProviderData** contains various data attributes that come from the particular data provider that this **ProviderData** instance represents and most importantly has many **tags** associated with it through *provider_data_tags*  many-to-many mapping table

```
class ProviderData < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :aggregate_data
  has_many :provider_data_tags
  has_many :tags, :through => :provider_data_tags
end
```

**Tag** is a simple model containing **name** attribute and many_to_many association with *ProviderData*. Note the finder function to get all tags associated with a provided **AggregateData**

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :provider_data_tags
  has_many :provider_datas, :through => :provider_data_tags

  def self.find_by_aggregate_data(ag_data)
    joins(:provider_datas).where(:provider_datas =>{:aggregate_data_id => ag_data.id})
  end
end
```

### The Problem: Top 10 tags for a specified AggregateData

So in my data model, **AggregateData** has a *score* and you can find which tags associated with this **AggregateData** using a scope or a **Tag.find_by_aggregate_data** function above

I need to get **TOP 10 TAGS** per **AggregateData**.

What this means is I need to get a subset of all the tags associated with an **AggregateData** for which the score of that **AggregateData** is in top 10 scores of all **AggregateDatas** associated with that particular tag.

So if  this **AggregateData** has tags *"java"*, *"ruby"*, *"javascript"*, *"html"*, *"css"* and the this **AggregateData** has the highest score of all **AggregateDatas** with a tag *"ruby"* and a highest score of all **AggregateDatas** with a tag *"javascript"*, but not the highest score for *"java"* or *"html"* or *"css"*, then this function/scope/query would return tags *"ruby"* and *"javascript"*

The solution would preferably use ActiveRecord/AREL notation, but I'm open to SQL suggestions which i can adapt to AR myself.

Comment: See the "greatest-n-per-group" tag - this is a very common request, and being that MySQL doesn't support ANSI analytic functions - is custom to MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a "ranking trick" in Mysql within a subquery, as described by [How to perform grouped ranking in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql).  Then, in your containing query, join on the results of te subquery and just add that the rank needs to be #1 and it has to map the current AggregateData item.  That is assuming that I'm interpreting correctly you only want to return the tags where the tags where the current AggregateData object is for the #1 tag.

Here's an idea of a script you could use in MySQL.  It may not be exactly right, but I think it gets the idea across.  You basically need to use some user variables to rank the items.

```
SET @last_tag_id = 0;

SELECT tag_id
FROM (
    SELECT tags.id AS tag_id, aggregate_datas.id AS agg_data_id, aggregate_datas.score, 
        (@rank := if(@last_tag_id = tags.id, @rank + 1, 0)) AS rank, 
        @last_tag_id := tags.id
    FROM aggregate_datas
    INNER JOIN provider_data_tags
    ON provider_data_tags.aggregate_data_id = aggregate_datas.id
    INNER JOIN tags
    ON tags.id = provider_data_tags.tag_id
    ORDER BY tags.id, aggregate_datas.score
) tag_ranks
WHERE tag_ranks.rank <= 10
AND agg_data_id = ?;
```

Comment: Thanks, ive actually restructured my data a little bit to simplify the ranking. Im still running into problems calculating top-n-in-group ranking due things like no LIMIT in subqueries, etc. Will try to rephrase the question

Comment: I'm sure you could use a nosql database, but I'm not sure it would be a case for it because I'm not sure how nosql would help with this one.  I'll update my answer with what I was thinking...  I think it will still work...