# SQL, multiple email adresses problem

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a user table (MySQL) with the following data

```
id  email       creation_date
1   bob@mail.com    2011-08-01 09:00:00
2   bob@mail.com    2011-06-24 02:00:00
3   john@mail.com   2011-02-01 04:00:00
4   john@mail.com   2011-08-05 20:30:00
5   john@mail.com   2011-08-05 23:00:00
6   jill@mail.com   2011-08-01 00:00:00
```

As you can see we allow email duplicates so its possible to register several accounts with the same email address. 
Now I need to select all adresses ordered by the creation_date but **no duplicates**. This is easy (i think)

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY creation_date) AS X GROUP BY email
```

Expected result:

```
id  email       creation_date
2   bob@mail.com    2011-06-24 02:00:00
6   jill@mail.com   2011-08-01 00:00:00
3   john@mail.com   2011-02-01 04:00:00
```

But then I also need to select all other adresses, ie. all that are not present in the result from the first query. *Duplicate are allowed* here.

Expected result:

```
id  email       creation_date
1   bob@mail.com    2011-08-01 09:00:00
4   john@mail.com   2011-08-05 20:30:00
5   john@mail.com   2011-08-05 23:00:00
```

Any ideas? Perfomance is important because the real database is very huge

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM a
FROM users a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT email, MIN(creation_date) as min_date GROUP BY email)x ON 
 (x.email = a.email AND x.min_date=a.creation_date)
WHERE x.email IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL server we would do a Select statement using a rank.

Here are some MYSQL samples:
[How to perform grouped ranking in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql)

http://thinkdiff.net/mysql/how-to-get-rank-using-mysql-query/

I hope this helps.