# SQL ranking view and group by

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anybody please tell me how to create a view which has a additional RANK column for a value column grouped by some other columns?

```
ID
BALANCE
GROUP2
GROUP1
GROUP0
unique (GROUP0, GROUP1, GROUP2)
```

The problem is the 'RANK' that the VIEW will calculate should be grouped by those `GROUP`s (say 0, 1, 2).

```
ID
BALANCE
GROUP2
GROUP1
GROUP0
RANK
```

Thanks.

EDIT -----------------------
I'm sorry I should explain more.
The `RANK` column is the `ranking by balance' for each group of (GROUP0, GROUP1, GROUP2)

So I want a vew looks like

```
ID  BALANCE  GROUP0  GROUP1  GROUP2  RANK
-----------------------------------------
    1000     0       0       0       1
    999      0       0       0       2
    1000     1       0       0       1
    999      1       0       0       2
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please add to tags the name and version of the database?

Comment: can you add a query that tries to do what you want but fails?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to perform grouped ranking in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql)

Comment: possible duplication, maybe right. i just a view creation technique. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not a clear question.
Is this what you want?

```
Select 
  id,
  balance,
  group1,
  group2,
  group3,
  row_number() over(partition by group1, group2, group3) as rank
from your_table.
```

You can add an order by in the over clause as needed, for example:

```
     row_number() over(partition by group1, group2, group3 order by id) as rank
```

Comment: uh oh.. MySQL doesn't support windowing function yet. that will not work

Comment: the answer where before the tag edit. I'll try a query in mysql if I have time.