# MySQL get unique and sorting

Tags: mysql, group-by

How can I select last 10 rows with unique **string1** entries and order them by id? Rows has following structure:

```
id | string1 | string2 | ... | stringN
```

Using **GROUP BY string1** along with **ORDER BY id DESC** result contains unique rows, but not from the tail of table.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use grouped ranking on `string1` column order by `ID` column, then select all the top 10 records whose rank is `1`, order by ID desc (if DESC ordering by ID gives you the tail of the table). If you need assistance in writing a group-ranking SQL for MySQL, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/532941/240078). SQL Server provides the [`RANK()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function out-of-the-box.