# Store a ranklist in a mysql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

Let have this table(`rank_list`).

```
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|  Sub   |  Name  |  Rank  | Marks  |
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
|Math2   |Smith   |       1|      85|
|Math1   |John    |       1|      92|
|Math1   |Susan   |       2|      91|
|Math1   |Abc     |       3|    90.5|
+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

Now I have four more results. I have to insert these on giving them correct rank. I also not accept that result which has a rank more than 3.

```
Sub = Math2,    Name = Mile,  Marks = 86
Sub = Math1,    Name = Luna,  Marks = 92.5
Sub = Physics1, Name = Sakib, Marks = 88.75
Sub = Math1,    Name = Coolb, Marks = 65
```

As `Mile` has a mark which ranked 2, he will be inserted as `Rank` 2.

Luna has higest marks, she'll get `Rank` 1 and `Abc` will be deleted (yes, deleted).

Sakib is from Physics1, so he will be inserted directly as he is currently ranked 1 in physics.

Coolb will not be inserted as he is not in top 3.

**I want MySQL query to do this.**

I can do this using `PHP`, but this will take much time. So, I want to do this using SQL (for faster insertion and deletion). And I need your help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: A better approach might be to insert the raw data into one table and use a view to represent the top ranked in each subject.

Comment: I agree with @IanMcMahon. Store all of the records, then just pull what you need when you need it.

Comment: What should happen on ties?

Comment: @ypercube- nothing, won't be inserted

Comment: @lan McMahon- no, if I do that, my table will be very weightful after an exam as there are more than 2000 users for each subject

Comment: Please clarify the "won't be inserted" bit that you replied to @ypercube. If there were two new `Math1` rows with the same `Marks` of `91`, would you like to disregard both, even though each of them would be greater than the third-ranked `Abc`? Or would you like to discard only one? In which case the natural question would be, "Which?".

Comment: @AndriyM- no, I will insert the first of them

Comment: Ah, first, right. That's seems to settle it. Except that there doesn't seem to be a way to tell which of them would be the first one. :) In which case the "first" would be chosen arbitrarily.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a piece of shamelessly stolen example from [How to perform grouped ranking in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql)

Your database design is not quite suited for it, but it does work and it wont get slow until you reach a very high number of rows, if you feel it is way too slow, you could always use a trigger and create a sort of "materialized view" with the current ranking.

Fiddle for testing: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b2cd8/15

SQL based on your table:

```
SELECT Name, Sub, Marks, Rank
FROM
    (SELECT Name, Sub, Marks,
        @student:=CASE WHEN @last_sub <> Sub THEN 1 ELSE @student+1 END AS Rank,
        @last_sub:=Sub
    FROM
        (SELECT @student:= 0) AS s,
        (SELECT @class:= 0) AS c,
        (SELECT * 
            FROM rank_list
            ORDER BY Sub, Marks DESC
        ) AS temp
    ) AS temp2
WHERE Rank <= 3
```

Comment: I do not want a ranklist. rather I want to insert a row if it has a place in the rank list. if the new row do not suits for the ranklist, it wont be inserted. what u've showed is getting a rank list from a table

Comment: Yes, I realize that. This is merely an example of how I think this should be done. Instead of what you are trying to achieve here.

To be able to do it your way, you would have to check if there are <3 records for the specific Sub, check if we are top 3 in Marks and if we are, insert us, recalculate Rank and then remove anyone with Rank 4 or above.