# mysql group ranking with ties

Tags: mysql

I found this Q&A here at [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql)  while searching for a way to group rank data. The solutions work perfectly but how does one account for ties within the groups?

So far I know how to rank, but I don't know how to account for the ties in groups.

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|   id         |   code       | score | rank |
+--------------------------------------------+ 
| 2477         |          312 |    64 |    1 |
| 1865         |          312 |    63 |    2 |
| 2511         |          312 |    62 |    3 |
| 2890         |          312 |    61 |    4 |
| 1335         |          312 |    61 |    5 |
| 1504         |          312 |    60 |    6 |
| 1385         |          312 |    60 |    7 |
| 1984         |          312 |    59 |    8 |
| 2477         |          212 |    64 |    1 |
| 1865         |          212 |    63 |    2 |
| 2511         |          212 |    62 |    3 |
| 2890         |          212 |    61 |    4 |
| 1335         |          212 |    61 |    5 |
| 1504         |          212 |    60 |    6 |
| 1385         |          212 |    60 |    7 |
| 1984         |          212 |    59 |    8 |
```

What I need is this:

```
+--------------------------------------------+
|   id         |   code       | score | rank |
+--------------------------------------------+ 
| 2477         |          312 |    64 |    1 |
| 1865         |          312 |    63 |    2 |
| 2511         |          312 |    62 |    3 |
| 2890         |          312 |    61 |    4 |
| 1335         |          312 |    61 |    4 |
| 1504         |          312 |    60 |    5 |
| 1385         |          312 |    60 |    5 |
| 1984         |          312 |    59 |    6 |
| 2477         |          212 |    64 |    1 |
| 1865         |          212 |    63 |    2 |
| 2511         |          212 |    62 |    3 |
| 2890         |          212 |    61 |    4 |
| 1335         |          212 |    61 |    4 |
| 1504         |          212 |    60 |    5 |
| 1385         |          212 |    60 |    5 |
| 1984         |          212 |    59 |    6 |
```

is there a way to get the above results?

Comment: combine your select with my counting of rating  :) http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e34de/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to assign same rank for same score with in same code group then you have to nest `case` statement

```
select `id`, `code`, `score`,rank
from (
select `id`, `code`, `score`,
@r:= case when @g = `code` 
     then 
         case when @s <> `score` then @r + 1 else @r end 
      else  1
       end rank,
@g:= `code`,
@s:= `score`
from table1 
cross join(select @g:=null,@r:=0,@s:=null) t
order by `code` desc, `score` desc
) t1
```

First `case` statement will check for same `code` group if there is same code found then in `then` part of parent `case` there will be another child `case` statement which will check if the score is different from the previous one then increment rank variable else assign same rank to the current row

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/57615/6)

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid.. your fiddle takes care of ties but ranking Is continuing throughout the groups