# MySQL Query Issues with Math not resulting in expected output

Tags: mysql, math, operator-precedence

**Overview:**

I built an application that I run locally which allows me to keep track of my kids chores and behaviors that they exhibit on a daily basis. This system has negative and positive behaviors I can assign to them which correspond to a point value on a `100` point scale.

**Logic:**

- The query only looks at the current day to calculate the points. If ratings were received the day prior, those will not play into their daily total.
- 100 points is the maximum a child can have for the day, even if their ratings cause them to exceed this, it will always return as `100`.
- If they don't have any ratings for the day (either positive or negative), it will default their points to the starting point `100`.
- When they receive points, their total will  adjust accordingly, either going up or down based on the value set for the behavior.

**Scenarios:**

1. New day without any ratings means the child starts at `100` points. They receive a negative behavior that has a `-3` value. This would return their `totalPoints` as `97`.
2. The above child then receives a positive rating worth `2` points which brings them up to `99` for their `totalPoints`.
3. They receive another positive rating worth `5` points. Since we max out at 100, we would return their `totalPoints` as `100`, regardless of how much it exceeded `100`.

**Issue:**

I built the query and thought everything was working fine but there seems to be a slight math issue with it. When the child received a `-3` point rating it brought them to `97` which was expected. I then gave them a positive `4` and it brought their score to `99` instead of `100` like I would have expected.

**Query:**

```
 SELECT c.id,
       c.NAME,
       Date_format(From_days(Datediff(CURRENT_DATE, c.age)),
       '%y Years %m Months %d Days')                                 AS age,
       c.photoname,
       c.photonamesmall,
       (SELECT CASE
                 WHEN ( Ifnull(Sum(t.points), (SELECT settingvalue
                                               FROM   settings
                                               WHERE  settingname = 'MaxPoints')
                        ) >= (
                        SELECT
                               settingvalue
                        FROM
                        settings
                        WHERE
                                 settingname = 'MaxPoints') ) THEN 100
                 WHEN ( Sum(t.points) <= 0 ) THEN ( (SELECT settingvalue
                                                     FROM   settings
                                                     WHERE  settingname =
                                                            'MaxPoints')
                                                    + Sum(t.points) )
                 ELSE ( (SELECT settingvalue
                         FROM   settings
                         WHERE  settingname = 'MaxPoints') -
                        Ifnull(Sum(t.points), (SELECT
                        settingvalue
                                               FROM   settings
                                               WHERE
                        settingname = 'MaxPoints')) )
               END
        FROM   behaviorratings AS r
               JOIN behaviortypes AS t
                 ON r.behaviorid = t.behaviortypeid
        WHERE  r.childid = c.id
               AND Date_format(r.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = Curdate()) AS
       totalPoints,
       (SELECT definitionname
        FROM   behaviordefinitions AS d
        WHERE  totalpoints BETWEEN d.min AND d.max)                  AS
       behaviorRating
FROM   children AS c
```

**Fiddle:**

Here is a link to the SQL fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa06c/1/0

The result I expect to see for Child 2 (Brynlee) is `100` not `99`.

She started with `100`, received a `-3` and the received a `+4`. While I know the math for this order of operations is correct, I need to it to be tweaked to reflect how I expected it to be reflected. `100 - 3 = 97` and then `97 + 4 = 101` (We max out at `100` so `100` would be the `totalPoints`.

Comment: How much the kid would have at the end of the day with points -3, +6, -2? 100 or 98?

Comment: @PaulSpiegel they would have 98 since its greater than the max points. 100-3 = 97.  97+6=103 ( so it's maxed at 100). 100-2 =98 as final total

Comment: this is sad. If I was your kid, i would just do nothing all the day ;-). It's not fair - if I do great stuff all the day (+20 = 100) and make a small mistake at the end (-2 = 98). To be serious: I don't think it's possible in SQL. You will need to iterate over all behaviors. But SQL is not a procedural language. You either need to use another language, or write a stored procedure. However, i would really change the rules :-)

Comment: @PaulSpiegel - That's true, didn't really think of it that way. I would probably need to start it right in the middle where it can go up or down so they have something to work towards. Now that I think about it, I think that's how it works in their school. They start in the middle on their chart and can go up or down accordingly.

Comment: This could be your query if you allow to exceed the limit of 100 during the day: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa06c/66

Comment: Thanks, @PaulSpiegel - That looks much cleaner. I will see if I can adjust things to tweak the logic for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT c.id,
   c.name,
   DATE_FORMAT(
    FROM_DAYS(
        DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, c.age)
    ),
    '%y Years %m Months %d Days'
  ) AS age,
   c.photoName,
   c.photoNameSmall,
   (SELECT CASE
             WHEN ( Ifnull(Sum(t.points), 0
                    ) + (SELECT settingValue
                                           FROM   settings
                                           WHERE  settingName = 'MaxPoints') >= (
                    SELECT
                           settingValue
                    FROM
                    settings
                    WHERE
                             settingName = 'MaxPoints') ) THEN 100
             WHEN ( Sum(t.points) <= 0 ) THEN ( (SELECT settingValue
                                                FROM   settings
                                                WHERE  settingName =
                                                       'MaxPoints')
                                               + Sum(t.points) )
             ELSE ( (SELECT settingValue
                     FROM   settings
                     WHERE  settingName = 'MaxPoints') -
                    Ifnull(Sum(t.points), (SELECT
                    settingvalue
                                           FROM   settings
                                           WHERE
                    settingName = 'MaxPoints')) )
           END
    FROM   behaviorRatings AS r
           JOIN behaviorTypes AS t
             ON r.behaviorID = t.behaviorTypeID
    WHERE  r.childid = c.id
           AND Date_format(r.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = Curdate()) AS
   totalPoints,
   (SELECT definitionName
    FROM   behaviorDefinitions AS d
    WHERE  totalPoints BETWEEN d.min AND d.max)                  AS
   behaviorRating
   FROM   children AS c
```

Basically, using

```
WHEN ( Ifnull(Sum(t.points), (SELECT settingvalue
                              FROM   settings
                              WHERE  settingname = 'MaxPoints')
)
```

will only give you 100 when sum(t.points) is null. To get total points you need to do

```
Ifnull(Sum(t.points), 0) + (SELECT settingvalue
                              FROM   settings
                              WHERE  settingname = 'MaxPoints')
```

This sql may make it easier to look at

```
SET @maxPoints := (SELECT settingValue
              FROM   settings
              WHERE  settingName = 'MaxPoints');

SELECT c.id,
   c.name,
   DATE_FORMAT(
    FROM_DAYS(
        DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, c.age)
    ),
    '%y Years %m Months %d Days'
  ) AS age,
   c.photoName,
   c.photoNameSmall,
   (SELECT CASE
             WHEN ( Ifnull(Sum(t.points), 0) + @maxPoints > @maxPoints ) THEN 100
             ELSE ( Ifnull(Sum(t.points), 0) + @maxPoints )
           END
    FROM   behaviorRatings AS r
           JOIN behaviorTypes AS t
             ON r.behaviorID = t.behaviorTypeID
    WHERE  r.childid = c.id
           AND Date_format(r.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = Curdate()) AS
   totalPoints,
   (SELECT definitionName
    FROM   behaviorDefinitions AS d
    WHERE  totalPoints BETWEEN d.min AND d.max)                  AS
   behaviorRating
   FROM   children AS c
```

Using 50 as starting point:

```
SET @maxPoints := (SELECT settingValue
          FROM   settings
          WHERE  settingName = 'MaxPoints');

SET @startingPoint := 50;

SELECT c.id,
c.name,
DATE_FORMAT(
FROM_DAYS(
    DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, c.age)
),
'%y Years %m Months %d Days'
) AS age,
c.photoName,
c.photoNameSmall,
(SELECT CASE
         WHEN ( Ifnull(Sum(t.points), 0) + @startingPoint > @maxPoints ) THEN 100
         ELSE ( Ifnull(Sum(t.points), 0) + @startingPoint )
       END
FROM   behaviorRatings AS r
       JOIN behaviorTypes AS t
         ON r.behaviorID = t.behaviorTypeID
WHERE  r.childid = c.id
       AND Date_format(r.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = Curdate()) AS
totalPoints,
(SELECT definitionName
FROM   behaviorDefinitions AS d
WHERE  totalPoints BETWEEN d.min AND d.max)                  AS
behaviorRating
FROM   children AS c
```

Sql for applying capping once total points exceeding limitation

```
SET @maxPoints := (SELECT settingValue
            FROM   settings
            WHERE  settingName = 'MaxPoints');

SET @startingPoint := 50;

SELECT 
    c.id,
    c.name,
    DATE_FORMAT(
    FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(CURRENT_DATE, c.age)), '%y Years %m Months %d Days') AS age,
    c.photoName,
    c.photoNameSmall,
    (
        select x.tp 
        from 
        (
            SELECT t.childid,
                @rn:=CASE WHEN @cid <> t.childid THEN 0 ELSE @rn+1 END AS rn,
                @startingPoint + @tp:= CASE 
                    WHEN @cid <> t.childid 
                    THEN ifnull(t.points, 0)
                    ELSE (
                        case when @startingPoint + t.points + @tp > @maxPoints 
                        then @maxPoints - @startingPoint
                        else t.points + @tp end)
                    END AS tp,
                @cid:=t.childid AS clset,
                t.timestamp
            FROM
                (SELECT @tp:= -1) p,
                (SELECT @rn:= -1) n,
                (SELECT @cid:= -1) cd,
                (
                    SELECT r.childid, t.points, r.timestamp
                    FROM behaviorRatings AS r
                    JOIN behaviorTypes AS t ON r.behaviorID = t.behaviorTypeID
                    ORDER BY r.childid, r.timestamp
                ) t
        ) x
        where x.childid = c.id AND Date_format(x.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = Curdate()
        order by x.childid, x.rn desc
        limit 1
    ) AS totalPoints,
    (
        SELECT definitionName
        FROM   behaviorDefinitions AS d
        WHERE  totalPoints BETWEEN d.min AND d.max
    ) AS behaviorRating
FROM   children AS c
```

Comment: This seemed to have fix the issue. I will use the feedback from Paul as well and probably change the 100 to 50 as the starting point. I think this same query will work if I update those numbers accordingly. 

Since I am using MySQL and PHP for the queries such as `$this->db->query(...)`, can I use `set` statements in those?

Comment: I don't know about php so you may need to try yourself: ) I will normally load all config into an object at beginning of my app, and use them to build my query.

Comment: I figured out the PHP part to run the set command so this helped. How difficult would it be to leave the `maxPoints` as `100` but their starting points, if they don't have any ratings for the day is `50`?

Comment: I didn't really try to understand this solution, neither the original query. As i wrote in another comment, it cannot work without any kind of iteration. Here is an example where i chanded the order of the behaviour (+4, -3). The result schould be 97. But you get 100 - http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0700f/1

Comment: @SBB Check out the edited answer, I add a sql that uses 50 as base point.

Comment: Per Paul's answer, I did some more testing and found that the issue still exists unfortunately. When increasing the point value past `100` and then deducting points, it is causing the issues again.

Comment: this query at the moment will check the sum of the points against 100. For example, if we start at 90 and have a sequence like: +4 +4 +4 -3, then you will get 99 as 90 + 4 + 4 + 4 - 3 = 99 and this is below 100. Do you want something that always cap at 100 once it is exceeded? in this case +4 +4 +4 -3 will give 97. but do you really want to cap at 100? does it means the kid will lose 2 points for no reason? @SBB

Comment: I changed the logic so that there is a starting point, and a max.

The max points you can earn, no matter what is 100. I chose this number because its easily represented on a progress indicator.

I decided to start the daily score at 50 points. This places them right in the middle of the spectrum. They can either do good and move up the chart or do bad and move down the chart.

I feel there needs to be a Cap in place to give the child something to aim for and work towards and want it to be attainable and not infinite.

Comment: hi @SBB, try the last query I just added to my answer. It may do what you want. I stolen an idea from this questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql

Comment: @EthanLi - Hmm, I got a `NULL` value on a child without ratings for the day and got `150` on the other child.

Comment: @SBB, just remove AND Date_format(x.timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d') = Curdate() in the condition. I think the server time is already 8th of Jan. Or update the data to match the time of curdate() function

Comment: @EthanLi - Those are all the behaviors I have applied to the child that is showing `150` points.

Comment: @SBB, solved, it should be 'then \@maxPoints - \@startingPointn' rather than 'then \@maxPoints'. checkout the last query again.

Comment: @EthanLi - It looks like the 100 points issue has been resolved. The only other thing I noticed with this code is that there is no starting value. When there are no ratings for a child, it returns `null` instead of `50`. Other than that, you nailed it!

Comment: @SBB, we must be missing a ifnull somewhere. I think you can figure it out. glad it works for you : )

Comment: @SBB, I added an ifnull in the last query which may solve the problem

Comment: I gave it a shot but it was still null. I will have another look shortly, thanks for getting me this far

Answer (score 0):

Don't make things more complicated than they should be. Choose the right language for your task. In you case it's PHP:

```php
$query = "select settingValue from settings where settingName = 'MaxPoints'";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
$row = $result->fetchAssoc();
$maxPoints = $row['settingValue'];

$query = "select * from children";
$result = $this->db->query($query);
$children = array();
while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $row['totalPoints'] = $maxPoints;
    $children[$row['id']] = $row;
}

$query = "
    select c.id, coalesce(bt.points, 0) as points
    from children c
    join behaviorRatings br on  br.childID = c.id
    join behaviorTypes bt on bt.behaviorTypeID = br.behaviorID
    where date(br.timestamp) = current_date()
    order by c.id, br.timestamp
";

$result = $this->db->query($query);
while ($row = $result->fetchAssoc()) {
    $childId = $row['id'];
    $totalPoints = $children[$row['id']]['totalPoints'];
    $totalPoints = $totalPoints + $row['points'];
    $totalPoints = min($totalPoints, $maxPoints);
    $children[$row['id']]['totalPoints'] = $totalPoints;
}

var_dump($children);
```

All the logic to get the total points is in the last loop. Now compare it to your query.

However - if you change the rules, allowing to exceed the limit during the day and cut the points only at the end of the day, this could be done in a single query:

```sql
select c.*, sub.totalPoints, bd.definitionName
from (
  select c.id, least(100+coalesce(sum(bt.points), 0), mp.settingValue) as totalPoints
  from children c
  join settings mp on settingName = 'MaxPoints'
  left join behaviorRatings br
    on  br.childID = c.id
    and date(br.timestamp) = current_date()
  left join behaviorTypes bt on bt.behaviorTypeID = br.behaviorID
  group by c.id
) sub
join children c on c.id = sub.id
join behaviorDefinitions bd on sub.totalPoints between bd.min and bd.max
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fa06c/71

While it is not a simple query, it is by far not as complex as your try. The accepded solution is doing the same ignoring the rule, that total points have to be cut to 100 every time points are gained (`Sum(t.points)`).

As I wrote in the comments: To follow that rule, you need some kind of iteration. There is a trick in MySQL using user variables:

```sql
select c.id, c.name, sub.totalPoints, bd.definitionName
from (
  select sub.childId, sum(sub.cuttedPoints) + sp.settingValue as totalPoints
  from (
    select 
      @points := coalesce(bt.points,0) as points,
      @lastTotalPoints := case when (c.id = @childId)
        then @totalPoints
        else sp.settingValue
      end lastTotalPoints,
      @totalPoints := least(@lastTotalPoints + @points, mp.settingValue) as totalPoints,
      @totalPoints - @lastTotalPoints as cuttedPoints,
      @childId := c.id as childId
    from children c
    join settings sp on sp.settingName = 'StartPoints'
    join settings mp on mp.settingName = 'MaxPoints'
    left join behaviorRatings br 
      on  br.childID = c.id
      and date(br.timestamp) = current_date()
    left join behaviorTypes bt on bt.behaviorTypeID = br.behaviorID
    cross join (select @childId := null) init_var
    order by c.id, br.timestamp
  ) sub
  join settings sp on sp.settingName = 'StartPoints'
  group by sub.childId
) sub
join children c on c.id = sub.childId
join behaviorDefinitions bd on sub.totalPoints between bd.min and bd.max
```

Result (Brynlee behaviour: +4 -3 +4 -3):

```
| id |    name | totalPoints |         definitionName |
|----|---------|-------------|------------------------|
|  2 | Brynlee |          97 | Having an amazing day! |
|  1 |    Maya |         100 | Having an amazing day! |
```

Brynlee gets 97 points as expected (+4 => 100, -3 => 97, +4 => 100, -3 => 97)

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/751c51/28

If you change the new setting "StartPoints" to 50 you will get:

```
| id |    name | totalPoints |   definitionName |
|----|---------|-------------|------------------|
|  2 | Brynlee |          52 | Not looking good |
|  1 |    Maya |          50 | Not looking good |
```

Here Brynlee gets 52 points because the limit of 100 was never reached (+4 => 54, -3 => 51, +4 => 55, -3 => 52).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/db020/13

This works because of MySQLs processing order. But this order depends on internal implementation of MySQL. This implementation may be changed in  future versions without any warning. I fact - MySQL developers explicitly warn of using user variables that way.

> As a general rule, other than in SET statements, you should never
>   assign a value to a user variable and read the value within the same
>   statement. For example, to increment a variable, this is okay:
>
> `SET @a = @a + 1;`
>
> For other statements, such as SELECT, you might get the results you
>   expect, but this is not guaranteed. In the following statement, you
>   might think that MySQL will evaluate @a first and then do an
>   assignment second:
>
> `SELECT @a, @a:=@a+1, ...;`
>
> However, the order of evaluation for expressions involving user
>   variables is undefined.

[**(User-Defined Variables)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html)

I only use "tricks" like that for one-way reports - But never in production code.

So my suggestion is: Change the rules or use a procedural language (PHP).

Comment: Thanks for this detailed post. I went through the code that was provided in the accepted answer and ran a few tests. It works just fine starting at `50`, going either up or down in points, all the way up to `100`. I then ran into the issue where I deducted `-3` from their 100 ranking and ended up with `99` again. I kept increasing their points well above `100` and then deducted `-3` and they remained at `100`. So, I do see that the issue still exists.

I changed the logic to start at `50` so that they can work up to something or can go down as well, however the issue is still there.

Comment: I will look into adapting your answer - seems like a lot of changes for something that seems to simple when I think about it.

Comment: While your answer goes into great details with a solution, could you explain why I am facing the issue? It is clearly happening but I am having a hard time understanding what/where something is/isn't happening.

Comment: @SBB You just didn't implement the rule, that `totalPoints` have to be limited to 100 every time points are gained.