# Sybase ASE: Compute ranks per grouped category

Tags: sql, t-sql, sybase, sap-ase, rank

I'm using Sybase ASE 15.7 which does not support `RANK()` or any other windowing functions.

I'm trying to compute ranks grouped per product category.

Consider the following `PRODUCTS` table with approximately 2 million records.

```
PROD_CATEGORY | PROD_NAME          | PROD_SALES  
---------------------------------------------  
Laptops       | Dell Inspiron      | 1000
Laptops       | Lenovo Thinkpad    | 800
Laptops       | Dell Latitude      | 500
Laptops       | Acer Aspire        | 1000
Printers      | Canon Pixma        | 2500
Printers      | HP OfficeJet       | 800
Printers      | HP DeskJet         | 1200
Desktops      | Lenovo ThinkCentre | 900
Desktops      | Asus Chromebox     | 300
Desktops      | HP Pavilion        | 1500
```

I'm trying to write a SQL query that'll compute ranks grouped per product category like below:

```
PROD_CATEGORY | PROD_NAME          | PROD_SALES | SALES_RANK  
------------------------------------------------------------  
Laptops       | Dell Inspiron      | 1000       | 1 
Laptops       | Lenovo Thinkpad    | 800        | 2
Laptops       | Acer Aspire        | 800        | 2
Laptops       | Dell Latitude      | 500        | 4
Printers      | Canon Pixma        | 2500       | 1
Printers      | HP DeskJet         | 1200       | 2
Printers      | HP OfficeJet       | 800        | 3
Desktops      | HP Pavilion        | 1500       | 1
Desktops      | Lenovo ThinkCentre | 900        | 2
Desktops      | Asus Chromebox     | 300        | 3
```

Note that products with the same `PROD_SALES` value generate a tied rank and the subsequent ranks have a gap in them.

To generate a rank without the `RANK()` function for all rows in the table, the standard SQL query given [here](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sql-rank.html) works well for the table with 2 million rows.

To generate the rank grouped per category, I tried the SQL query given [here](https://rickosborne.org/blog/2008/01/sql-getting-top-n-rows-for-a-grouped-query/) without success as the query takes a long time and did not complete execution.

Is there a way to generate this rank per grouped category that will work with Sybase ASE?

This question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql) SO question that was asked for MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the rank with a correlated subquery:

```
select p.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from products p2
        where p2.prod_category = p.prod_category and p2.prod_sales > p.prod_sales
       ) as rnk
from products p;
```