# mysql pivot query 2 tables left join

Tags: mysql, pivot

I have trouble creating what i can read from other threads is called a PIVOT table.

Think the answer is in this article http://stratosprovatopoulos.com/web-development/mysql/pivot-table-with-dynamic-columns/ but cant get my head around it

I have a table of products and a table of images
One product can have many images.

If i helps lets say that one product can have up to 8 images.

PRODUCT

```
+----------+-------------+
|ProductId | ProductName |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | ProductA    |
+----------+-------------+
|        2 | ProductB    |
+----------|-------------+
```

IMAGE

```
+----------+-------------+
|ProductId | ImageName   |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | FileA       |
+----------+-------------+
|        1 | FileB       |
+----------|-------------+
|        2 | FileC       |
+----------|-------------+
```

What I have now

```
SELECT p.ProductId, ProductName, ImageName
FROM PRODUCT p
LEFT JOIN IMAGE i
ON p.ProductId = i.ProductId
```

```
+----------+-------------+-----------+
|ProductId | ProductName | ImageName |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
|        1 | ProductA    | FileA     |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
|        1 | ProductA    | FileB     |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
|        2 | ProductB    | FileC     |
+----------+-------------+-----------+
```

What I need

```
+----------+-------------+---------+---------+
|ProductId | ProductName | Image1  | Image2  |
+----------+-------------+---------+---------+
|        1 | ProductA    | FileA   | FileB   |
+----------+-------------+---------+---------+
|        2 | ProductB    | FileC   |         |
+----------+-------------+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Seriously consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: See if [`GROUP_CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) could be an option.

Comment: For a pivot to work, you need one of the tables to contain `Image1`, `Image2`, etc. as columns. If you don't have that, you'll need to create it using a query with a user-defined variable that increments, as when creating a Rank. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql for how to do that within each group.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT is near what i need
SELECT p.product_id, productName,
         GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.filename SEPARATOR ';') AS image
       FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN image i ON p.product_id = i.product_id
       GROUP BY p.product_id

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do the pivot with the way you display your data. There is no way to give dynamic column names to the pivoted table. As Barmar mentioned you would need to write a ranking function that would display a dynamic value for eact repetition of productid (e.g. 'File 1', 'File 2', 'File 3', etc.). Which is an over complication.

Use PM 77-1 solution and group_concat if you just need to get all the image pathes into a single row. You can always then split it by ','.