# Update group by elements using sequence

Tags: mysql, sql

how can i do something like this:

I have two tables, A and B. **A --> B is one to many**.

**B** has a **varchar** field that we will call **field1**.

I have also a sequence **seq1** that i want to use in this way:

Suppose we have **A1** and **A2**, two records belonging to table **A**. **A1** has (B1,B2,B3,B4) and **A2** has (B5,B6).

I want to use the sequence for each group and start from the beginning each time i change group to update field1 in B. So i will have somthing like

B1.field1 = 1, B2.field1 = 2, B3.field1 = 3, B4.field1 = 4

now the sequence start back from 1 for A2:

B5.field1 = 1, B6.field2 = 2.

Is there some complex nested structure to do that or i need a function?

I was thinking about using a temporary table ,playing a bit on indexes and sub countings but i don't manage to find a wayout.

Thanks

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Use a user-defined variable in a join, just like you would to generate per-group ranking in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/532878/how-to-perform-grouped-ranking-in-mysql

Comment: Then you simply set `field1` to the rank variable.