# SQL statement that organizes a series of items, one per set

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to write a sql statement that lists a series of products that all belong to sets to be ordered one per set, and list through all of the products.

My products are organized like this.

**Set 01**
Product 01
Product 02
Product 03

**Set 02**
Product 06
Product 07
Product 08
Product 09

**Set 03**
Product 11
Product 12
Product 13
Product 14
Product 15

I’d like to create a sql query that organizes them like this

**Set 01** - Product 01
**Set 02** - Product 06
**Set 03** - Product 11
**Set 01** - Product 02
**Set 02** - Product 07
**Set 03** - Product 12
**Set 01** - Product 03
**Set 02** - Product 08
**Set 03** - Product 13
**Set 02** - Product 09
**Set 03** - Product 14
**Set 03** - Product 15

I can get a query of products grouped by set, but am unable to get one per set.

```
select 
       `product_set`.`product_id`, 
       `product_set`.`set_id`,
       `product_set`.`order` 
from 
       `product_set` 
inner join 
       `sets` 
on  
       `product_set`.`set_id` = `sets`.`id` 
where 
       `condition` = true
```

Comment: if this was `sql-server` done deal...

Comment: @mastashufu seems pretty straightforward to me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can enumerate the values by set:

```
select ps.*
from (select ps.*,
             (@rn := if(@s = set_id, @rn + 1,
                        if(@s := set_id, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      from (select ps.product_id, ps.set_id, ps.order 
            from product_set ps join 
                 sets s
                 on ps.set_id = s.id
            where s.conditionk = true
            order by ps.set_id, ps.order
           ) ps cross join
           (select @s := -1, @rn := 0) params
      ) ps
order by rn, set_id;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely. The other answer was slightly more efficient so I marked that one correct.

Comment: @whoacowboy . . . Unfortunately, it is *not* correct, because MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions.  You might not even know if it weren't producing the correct results.

Comment: I just discovered that and switched the correct answer, thank you, again.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/532941/4770578

You need to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT product_id, set_id,
        @product:=CASE WHEN @set <> set_id THEN 0 ELSE @product+1 END AS rn,
        @set:=set_id AS r_set
    FROM
        (SELECT @product:= -1) s,
        (SELECT @set:= -1) c,
        (SELECT *
            FROM product_sets
            ORDER BY set_id, product_id
        ) t
    ) t1
ORDER BY rn, set_id, product_id;
```

Creating row numbers for each of your rows and then sorting by those row numbers.

Comment: Thank you, this worked nicely. Actually the other answer worked as well but yours was slightly more efficient (7ms) and you answered first.

Comment: Sorry to switch the correct answer. I was getting some funky results with the query after I investigated it further. Thank you all the same.