# Number rows not column id

Tags: php

```
    $query = mysql_query("
    SELECT * FROM comments
    ORDER BY comments.comment_date ASC");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    .......
    }
```

How would I do to "number" the comments.

like  [this site](http://fragbite.com/?threadID=522519&commentPage=1#comments)

you know...

1.
 
2.
3.
4.
5.
...

Thanks

Comment: Very similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431053/what-is-the-best-way-to-generate-ranks-in-mysql

Answer (score 3):

```
$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
   $i++;
   print $i; 
   .......
}
```

You can count in your cycle, so you get a consistent numbering not related to the database! =)

Answer (score 3):

You could also use an orderer list (`OL` element).

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("
SELECT * FROM comments
ORDER BY comments.comment_date ASC");
$num = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    echo $num++;
    .......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, my background is more in MS SQL than MySQL, but it sounds like you're looking for a way to accomplish what ROW_NUMBER() ([msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)) accomplishes in MS SQL 2005. Prior to 2005, one way to number result rows was accomplished by creating a Stored Procedure to return a table variable (or temporary table).  So you'd create a temporary representation of the table, including a new column for RowNum and have the stored procedure return the new table. For example...

*These are MS SQL Commands, but I assuming MySQL ones are similar*

```
CREATE TABLE @TempComments
(
    RowNum smallint not null IDENTITY(1,1),
    ...other fields...
)

INSERT INTO @TempComments (all fields except RowNum)
SELECT * FROM comments
```

Have the stored procedure return `@TempComments` to your application and now you have a comments table with a sequential Row number for each row.

Looks like MySQL implemented Stored Procedures in version 5.0, so hopefully that's what you're using.

Hope that helps, others feel free to add the proper MySQL syntax.

Comment: Down voted... creating a stored procedure when you just want to know the the number of the iteration is really, really, reaaaaaaaally overkill and thus a bad advice.