# mysql & php: temporary/ virtual ids for query results?

Tags: php, mysql, temp-tables

I wonder if it is possible to assign temporary/ virtual IDs for a query result?

For instance, I have this as my query,

```
SELECT 

pg_id AS ID,
pg_url AS URL,
pg_title AS Title,
pg_content_1 AS Content

FROM root_pages

ORDER BY pg_created DESC
```

output:

```
ID  URL     Title   Content 
53  a       A       xxx 
40  b       B       xxx 
35  c       C       xxx
```

you can see the the gap between the IDs - they are very untidy. I wonder if I can make a virtual column or something so that I have the output below,

```
ID  URL     Title   Content  Virtual ID
53  a       A       xxx      3
40  b       B       xxx      2
35  c       C       xxx      1
```

from a query like this below,

```
SELECT 

pg_id AS ID,
pg_url AS URL,
pg_title AS Title,
pg_content_1 AS Content

FROM root_pages

ORDER BY virtual_id DESC
```

is it possible??

thanks!

Comment: why do you need the virtual id for?

Comment: so that i can do this - ORDER BY virtual_id DESC

Comment: you still can with the id alone?

Comment: yes it can with the id alone. but it doesnt output 'correctly' when I if I query the odd IDs or even IDs - WHERE MOD(pg_id,2) = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you still persist on getting the position of each row
take a look at this answer

[MySQL get row position in ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by)

Comment: thanks. but it is a single row output - not what I am looking for I am afraid... cheers

Comment: if you remove the  WHERE t.name = 'Beta' then you get data for all the rows?

Comment: I tried with this (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM root_pages) AS position. then it creates a same newest number for each row...

Comment: i have found a solution - http://craftycodeblog.com/2010/09/13/rownum-simulation-with-mysql/ thanks for your replies that led me to it! :)