# Order by VARCHAR value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have a table with 2 columns

```
id  status

1   SUBMIT
2   CANCEL
3   UPDATE
4   CANCEL
5   SUBMIT
6   UPDATE
```

If I do:

```
select * from table
```

Can I order the results in the order I want using MySQL?
ASC would be CANCEL,SUBMIT,UPDATE and DESC the reverse. What if I want a different order like SUBMIT,CANCEL,UPDATE? Is it possible?

Comment: this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857036/mysql-concecutive-order-positions might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood correctly, this is what you need:

```
SELECT * FROM `Table` ORDER BY FIELD(status, 'SUBMIT', 'CANCEL', 'UPDATE');
```

You can change the order of colum values to correspond your demand.

Here's the test:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1885/3

Answer (score 0):

For your case ::

```
Select status from table group by status
```

will give the result you need

Answer (score 0):

When you search for [mysql custom sort order](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[mysql]+custom+sort+order) you will find lots of examples. One of them is `order by case`

```
select *
from mytable
order by case status when 'SUBMIT' then 1
                     when 'CANCEL' then 2
                     when 'UPDATE' then 3
         end
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a749/1/0)