# PDO MySQL row location in result

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am building an application to store "scores" in a database, and I want to be able to tell people how they are ranking.

So right now, I have my select query that grabs all the database rows and sorts them descending by score, so the scores are highest to lowest.

Now what I want, is to be able to show each user their individual rank... so if Jim is ranked 33 in that list, it will show him on his workstation that his rank is 33...

So how can I get what row number Jim falls on in the result set? (They are sorted by unique employee id's... but I think you get the point)

So if Jim logs in he can see something like: You have 670 points your rank is 33.

I am using PDO on MySQL.

I hope that description makes sense.

Comment: While you are looping through the query result, keep a `$count` variable incrementing each row. This will give you the rank since it will be in the 33rd loop over

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get user rank with MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363388/get-user-rank-with-mysql)

Answer (score 0):

My example is with MySQLi, but the logic is the same for PDO/MySQL

Assuming $con is your database connection variable:

```
 $All_Users = $con->query("SELECT * FROM Users ORDER BY Score DESC"); // Get all users and order by descending order.

    $rank = 0;
        while($UserInfo = $All_Users->fetch_object()) {
          $rank++;
          echo $UserInfo->Username."has a rank of". $rank;
        }
```

The output will be in the following format, in this case we have only 2 users in our Users table, ordered by descending id:

Bob has a rank of 3 
Joe has a rank of 2 
Pete has a rank of 1

If you change DESC to ASC in the mysql query, the output will be:

Pete has a rank of 1 
Joe has a rank of 2 
Pete has a rank of 3