# renumber items in a row selection

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have a number of rows in a selection with a sort index like

```
ID   text  date         sort_index
43   ABC   2013-05-28   3
93   DEF   2013-05-28   14
12   ABC   2013-05-28   103
[...]
```

Now I would like to renumber the `sort_index` from 0 to 2. The group element is `date`.
How can I do that by using MySQL?

Comment: You mean you want sort_index to be the ID of the row of the results?

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by

Comment: Also, do you wish to update your actual table based on the results of the query?

Comment: Yes - I would like to update the table!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, but not tested for every case yet.

```
UPDATE tbltest SET sort_index =
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
        SELECT * FROM tbltest
    ) AS dup
    WHERE  dup.`date` = tbltest.`date` AND
           dup.sort_index < tbltest.sort_index
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out [this](http://paulwhippconsulting.com/blog/renumbering-an-ordering-field-in-mysql/) site.

In your case it would go like this:

```
mysql> SET @ordering_inc = 1;
mysql> SET @new_ordering = -1;
mysql> UPDATE YOUR_TABLE SET 
       sort_index = (@new_ordering := @new_ordering + @ordering_inc)
       WHERE date = '2013-05-28'
       ORDER BY sort_index ASC;
```

Not tested!

Comment: Yep..this does the trick! If  I hadn't reached my voting limit I'd +1

Comment: I believe this only work for one specific date, while OP want a single query that works with many date inside the table.

Comment: You can always remove WHERE date = '2013-05-28' , which means you can easily make it work for all dates.

Comment: Of course, it will work differently when remove WHERE, but not as OP intended.