# MySQL ranking with GROUP BY and SUM

Tags: mysql

I have a point table with some columns being:

```
| user_id | points |
--------------------
|   1     |   10   |
|   5     |   10   |
|   5     |   50   |
|   3     |   15   |
|   3     |   10   |
```

I would like to get the rank for each user with MySQL.

I've seen this post [MySQL get row position in ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by) but it doesn't have a SUM in it and I can't get it to work with SUM.

I would like to be able to get the rank of a given user_id.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reminding the OP's question:

> I would like to be able to get the rank of a given user_id.

In order to actually perform operations over the `@rank` you have to user another derived table (yes, it is inefficient, that's why it is better not to handle this in MySQL):

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT s.*, @rank := @rank + 1 rank FROM (
    SELECT user_id, sum(points) TotalPoints FROM t
    GROUP BY user_id
  ) s, (SELECT @rank := 0) init
  ORDER BY TotalPoints DESC
) r
WHERE user_id = 3
```

**Output**

```
| USER_ID | TOTALPOINTS | RANK |
|---------|-------------|------|
|       3 |          25 |    2 |
```

The process is basically:

1. Get the total amounts of points per user
2. Sort by those total points ranking
3. Filter once you have the rank (otherwise, the rank will be compromised)

Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3b4f9/1).

Comment: Thanks for your thorough answer. I am not good with subqueries :D

Answer (score 3):

Try this::

```
SELECT @rownum:=@rownum + 1 as row_number, 
       t.*
FROM ( 

select user_id, SUM(points) as Addedpoint
from mytable group by user_id order by Addedpoint desc

) t,
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with subquery, inside which you should calculate your sum:

```
SELECT 
  @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, 
  user_id, 
  total_points 
FROM 
  (SELECT 
    user_id, 
    SUM(points) AS total_points 
  FROM t 
  GROUP BY 
    user_id) AS sum_points 
CROSS JOIN 
  (SELECT @rank:=0) AS init 
ORDER BY 
  sum_points.total_points DESC
```

-see my [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/17a92/1).

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
@rownum := @rownum + 1 AS position, 
user_id, 
total_points

from
(select user_id, sum(points) as total_points from table)a 
join 
(SELECT @rownum := 0) r
order by total_points desc
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a user variable you can do something like this:-

```
SELECT user_id, tot_points, @Rank:=@Rank + 1 AS user_rank
FROM
(
    SELECT user_id, SUM(points) AS tot_points
    FROM SomeTable
    GROUP BY user_id
    ORDER BY tot_points DESC
) Sub1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank:=0) Sub2
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0be9/1

```
SET @rank=0;
select @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, pointsScored.user_id, sumPoints
from (
   select user_id , SUM(points)as sumPoints
   from point
   group by user_id 
   order by  sumPoints desc
)as pointsScored
```