# In a SQL select statement, how could one calculate a position of a row?

Tags: mysql, sql

The MySQL database table:

```
create table t (
  visitor_id int(11),
  activity_type varchar(10),
  date date
);
```

The rows:

```
insert into t (visitor_id, activity_type, date) values (1, 'hit',   '2012-1-1');
insert into t (visitor_id, activity_type, date) values (1, 'event', '2012-1-2');
insert into t (visitor_id, activity_type, date) values (2, 'hit',   '2012-1-2');
insert into t (visitor_id, activity_type, date) values (2, 'event', '2012-3-5');
insert into t (visitor_id, activity_type, date) values (2, 'hit',   '2012-3-2');
insert into t (visitor_id, activity_type, date) values (1, 'hit',   '2012-3-5');
insert into t (visitor_id, activity_type, date) values (1, 'hit',   '2012-2-1');
```

I want to write a query to retrieve a data dump of users, activity type, and the order in which the activity occurred, that looks like the following:

```
visitor_id, activity_type, Position 
1,          hit,              1 
1,          event,            2 
1,          hit,              3 
1,          hit,              4 
2,          hit,              1 
2,          hit,              2 
2,          event,            3
```

So far I have written the following solution:

```
select visitor_id, activity_type, 'Position'
from t1
order by visitor_id, date
;
```

The hard part is the column Position.  This should represent the position in the order of the rows for that visitor ID.  Is there any way to determine Position?

Comment: SQL doesn't guarantee an order unless you specify an `ORDER BY` clause. `position` doesn't mean very much. If you TIMESTAMP everything (as opposed to date) that might give you a start

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL get row position in ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be relevant to your question:

[MySQL get row position in ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by)