# PHP & MYSQL - GET POSITION OF ROW

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Can you return the position of the row in comparison to the previous search. For example if I did a simple query: `select * from table where name='aa'`

it would return

```
+--+----+---+
|id|name|cid|
+--+----+---+
| 1|  aa|  2|
| 5|  aa|  2|
| 8|  aa|  2|
| 9|  aa|  2|
|10|  aa|  2|
+--+----+---+
```

If I changed that query to:
`select * from table where name='aa' and id='5'`

it would return

```
+--+----+---+
|id|name|cid|
+--+----+---+
| 5|  aa|  2|
+--+----+---+
```

now according to the first search for `where name='aa'` there are 5 rows with `and id='5'` being the second row.

So, is there a way to get the position of the row in comparison to initial set? I'd like to be able to print "Result 2 of 5". I can get the number `5` by counting the total rows. I just need to get the position of the `and id='5'`. Which I know is the second row of the initial set but I can't seem to figure out a way to return that information. Forgive me if I'm not explaining this properly as I don't quite know how to ask this question.

Comment: The concept of position is pretty much meaningless in SQL, which is built around set theory.  Why would you want to do this anyway?

Comment: Remember - there's no "native order" in SQL. There's "order by some column". And you need to decide which column to use

Comment: Normally, in displaying results from mysql when I'm displaying sets or paginating the data I use limit and can very easily get the position of the row. With the application I'm working on now I just need to get the current, next and previous result so there is no "limit" in the query, and nothing to base position off of.

Comment: You're referring to some way, which DBMS stores your data. But let my clarify - is your order defined by `id` column? I.e. by "second" in row set you mean "there's one row with id lesser than this"

Comment: By "second" I mean, `and id=5` pulls the second row of the initial set of data provided by `where name='aa'`

Comment: As others have noted SQL will give you the results without any hard ordering guarantee. You can enforce that by using `ORDER BY` in your query, which will sort them relative to each other. You can then take the results one by one in your host app, etc. with `mysqli_fetch_row` in PHP. If you want to preserve the order by which each row was entered in the DB, you need to introduce a new column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite that fact, that *natural order* has no sense in SQL - it seems, you're referring to ordering by `id` column. Then your position is just count of rows with `id` lesser or equal to this:

```
SELECT 
  *, 
  (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `table` WHERE name='aa' AND id<=5) AS position
FROM 
  `table` 
WHERE 
  name='aa' AND id=5
```

Comment: I'm not ordering by ID but I understand what your example does and it worked for exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Comment: This is all I actually needed:

`select count(1) from table where name='aa' and x<=X`

with `x` being the column that i'm ordering by and `X` being the value for the current row i need the position of in relation to the fullset that `select * from table where name='aa'` provides.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the first SQL statement, then if you are wanting to search for the id of 5 in that specific name you could use a small loop, for example:

```
    $rows = $stmt->FetchAll() //Your Fetched Rows
    $cnt = 1;
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if ($row['id']==$id) {
            return $cnt
        } else {
            $cnt++
        }
    }
```

I am not sure if SQL is capable of handling more complex situations as the one you are describing, but maybe someone here has more knowledge in this area than me.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking of doing something along the lines of this but I just feel like there is someway in mysql to return the position of the `and id='5'` in comparison to the `where name='aa'`, idk though.

Comment: Here, I think I may have found something for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by