# Pagination - Calculate the page which certain row will appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, pagination, datatables

I'm using [jQuery DataTables](http://www.datatables.net/) to build a grid, with AJAX loaded data and pagination.

I built a form to create a new record, save it on the database and reload the grid. I would like to selected the last inserted record.

The problem is: the grid only shows 10 records. How would be the logic to calculate in what page the last row will appear to navigate to it?

Comment: This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL get row position in ORDER BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After your record is added you can refresh the table details like bellow

```
var oTable = jQuery('#infotable').dataTable({
//your code
 });
```

now after new record added success after ajax just call fnDraw. it will load your newly added record

```
jQuery.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'your url',
                data: yourdata,
                success: function(data){
                    oTable.fnDraw();
                }
            });
```