# PHP - position in table

Tags: php, mysql, position, row

How can I find the position a certain row has in my database table?

In my database I have a bunch of Players from a game. They have columns such as ID, name, level, world, and so on.

I want to sort them by Level, and see what position they are in in the list.

So far I've tried this, but it only prints out 0 (the start value I put). It does not seem to iterate through.

Previously I made sure the name is stored in `$name`.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM rookstayers ORDER BY level DESC";

$globalPos = 0;
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num = mysql_numrows($result);
$i = 0;
while($i < $num) {
    $posName = mysql_result($result, $i, 'name');
    if($posName == '$name')
    {
        $globalPos = $i;
        break;
    }

    $i++;
}
```

If my table looks like this (after sorting it by level):

```
name - level
Joe - 50
Jacob - 47
Sarah - 34
Anna - 19
```

Then "Sarah" would be number 3.
Anna number 4, etc...

I want the position-number to be in `$globalPos`.

I only found pure SQL code for this, but I want it in PHP. Is it not possible to do in PHP?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rank function in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3333665/rank-function-in-mysql)

Comment: yes but that's sql, i dont know much about it. i found nothing in php

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by

Comment: does it return 0 for any name? cause you receive 0 for Joe unless you change `$globalPos = $i;` to `$globalPos = $i+1;`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the only problem:

If you use single quotes `'`, the string is not parsed for variables. If you want to compare a string stored in `$name` with a string stored in `$posName`, you should use `$posName === $name`. You could also use `$posName === "$name"`, but the double quotes are unnecessary.

Notice also, that the `mysql` functions are deprecated. You should use `mysqli` or `PDO_MySQL` instead. (See [Choosing an API](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php))

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

/*

CREATE TABLE results
(name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,score INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO results VALUES
('Anna',19),
('Jacob',47),
('Joe',50),
('Sarah',34);

*/

include('path/to/connection/stateme.nts');

$query = "

SELECT name, score FROM results ORDER BY score DESC;

";

$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

$i=1;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

echo $i." ".$row['name']." ".$row['score']."<br/>\n";
$i++;
};

?>
```