# How can I "iterate" over a query in a view?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the the following SQL query.

```sql
SELECT
    us.foo,
    us.user_id_2,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM my_table x
        WHERE x.foo >= us.foo
            AND x.user_id_2 = 53
    ) AS position
FROM my_table us
WHERE us.user_id_1 = 53
ORDER BY position;
```

This gives me results like this:

| foo | user_id_2 | position |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 687 | 0 |
| 40 | 9832 | 1 |
| 39 | 12 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

This can be interprted as follows: User `687` is the first match for user `53` with score `42`. User `9832` is the second match with score `49` and so on.
My problem is that the user is `53` is hardcoded in the query.
I need the results for every user in the `users` table.
To be more precisely, I want something like this:

| foo | user_id_1 | user_id_2 | position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 42 | 53 | 687 | 0 |
| 40 | 53 | 9832 | 1 |
| 39 | 53 | 12 | 2 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 193 | 12 | 53 | 0 |
| 175 | 12 | 9832 | 1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

What I basically want is iterating over `SELECT id FROM users` use that id instead my hardcoded `53` from my query.

Ordering does not matter here. I'm using MariadDb 10.3.

How can I do this?

The structure of `my_table` is:

| user_id_1 | user_id_2 | foo |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 53 | 687 | 42 |
| 687 | 53 | 42 |
| 53 | 9832 | 40 |
| 9832 | 53 | 40 |
| 53 | 9832 | 39 |
| 9832 | 53 | 39 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Comment: Why can't you correlate your subquery using `user_id`?

Comment: This would not work with position finding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614666/mysql-get-row-position-in-order-by
What my query does is finding the position that user `53` has in view of all other users.

Comment: Please [edit] the question, and share more details (in this question) about where/how you do find this `53`.

Comment: remove `WHERE us.user_id_1 = 53` and change `AND x.user_id_2 = 53` to `AND x.user_id_2 = us.user_id_1`, does it produce what you need

Comment: Remove the WHERE clause of the main query and change to: `WHERE x.foo >= us.foo            AND x.user_id_2 = us.user_id_1`. This is what your query does only for user 53. By correlating the subquery you expand to all users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
    us.foo,
    us.user_id_1,
    us.user_id_2,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM my_table x
        WHERE x.foo >= us.foo
            AND x.user_id_2 = us.user_id_1
    ) AS position
FROM my_table us
ORDER BY user_id_1, position;
```

See [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=95d0c11c9152022023cb57df6395011a).