# mysql select ordernumber by group

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying to do something like 'select groupwise maximum',  but I'm looking for groupwise order number.

so with a table like this

```
briefs
----------
id_brief | id_case | date
1        | 1       | 06/07/2010
2        | 1       | 04/07/2010
3        | 1       | 03/07/2010
4        | 2       | 18/05/2010
5        | 2       | 17/05/2010
6        | 2       | 19/05/2010
```

I want a result like this

```
breifs result
----------
id_brief | id_case | dateOrder
1        | 1       | 3
2        | 1       | 2
3        | 1       | 1
4        | 2       | 2
5        | 2       | 1
6        | 2       | 3
```

I think I want to do something like described here [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select), but I don't know how I would reset the variable for each id_case.

Comment: The last row in the result should be `6 | 3 | 1 `, right?

Comment: Please clarify your question, the example is abiguous.

Comment: You want to do a rank(order by date partition by id_case) from oracle. Look at http://onlamp.com/pub/a/mysql/2007/03/29/emulating-analytic-aka-ranking-functions-with-mysql.html?page=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you how many records are there with this `id_case` value and a date less than or equal to this `date` value.

```
SELECT t1.id_brief,
    t1.id_case,
    COUNT(t2.*) AS dateOrder
FROM yourtable AS t1
    LEFT JOIN yourtable AS t2 ON t2.id_case = t1.id_case AND t2.date <= t1.date
GROUP BY t1.id_brief
```

Mysql is permissive about columns which can be queries using GROUP BY. With a more stric DBMS you may need `GROUP BY t1.id_brief, t1.id_case`.

I **strongly** advise you to have *the right indexes* on the table:

```
CREATE INDEX filter1 ON yourtabl (id_case, date)
```

Comment: If I change <= to >= it gives me the order I want.  Well done giving the correct answer to an ambiguous question ;)