# How to get a nested sub-query to recognize parent query column

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions, subquery

I have a problem where I'm trying to calculate a sum of values per given id. I decided to do this using sub-queries (typically I'd use a join, but I'm also keeping a counter for each sub-query for clipping purposes - [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075643/use-table-column-value-for-limit-when-performing-join) for more info). For the sake of this question, assume I have the following **MySQL** query:

```
/* 1.  */  SELECT 
/* 2.  */      t1.experiement_id,
/* 3.  */      (SELECT  sum(x.size) 
/* 4.  */       FROM    (SELECT size, ( @rownum := @rownum + 1 ) AS `rownum`
/* 5.  */                FROM   data AS t0 
/* 6.  */                JOIN ( select @rownum := 0 ) 
/* 7.  */                WHERE  t0.experiment_id = t1.experiment_id
/* 8.  */                ORDER BY size) AS x
/* 9.  */                WHERE x.rownum <= t2.clip_index ) AS `sum`
/* 10. */  
/* 11. */  FROM data      AS t1
/* 12. */  JOIN data_clip AS t2 USING (experiment_id)
/* 13. */  
/* 14. */  GROUP BY t1.experiment_id
```

The problem happens on row `7`, where I'm trying to isolate the rows in the sub-query that matches `experiement_id` - I'm getting an error that `t1.experiement_id` is an unknown column. This only happens on a query that's nested more than 1 level deep. Just as a check, I've noticed that `t2.clip_index` is being processed fine. If I comment out row #7, the query returns fine (albeit with wrong results). Any idea how to make the sub-query recognize the parent table's column to use in my condition? Thanks.

Comment: I've the same problem, have you found a solution ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this for counting rows instead of the user-defined variable ?

```
(SELECT sum(size) FROM  data AS t0                  
WHERE  t0.experiment_id = t1.experiment_id
ORDER BY size HAVING COUNT(*)<=t2.clip_index
) AS `sum`
```

Let me know if this works, it is an interesting issue we are examining here.