# How would I change this code to make the data group properly?

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, jtable

Here is my code, it does its job, mostly but it isn't grouping like I told it to using an SQL statemnt. Also I was wondering how I could make a custom column that numbers itself so that the top is '1' and it numbers down from there.

```
btnLeaderBoardUpdate.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            String sql3 ="Select Name, Kills from honscores group by Name, Kills order by Kills DESC";
            ResultSet rs;
            try {
                st = conn.prepareStatement(sql3);
                rs = st.executeQuery();
                table_2.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

            } catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            }

        }
    });
```

Here is the output:( I want to add a column before the current two called rank and have it number from 1)

```
Name           Kills

Raknath        20

AceFire6       15

AceFire6       12

AceFire6       10

Raknath        9

Q22            7

Q22            5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your first issue, see below.

**Short answer**
Use this statement instead:

```
Select Name, sum(Kills) from honscores group by Name order by Kills DESC
```

**Long answer**
You do not want to group by kills but only by name and want to aggregate the result.

Assuming you have this data:

```
AceFire6  2
AceFire6  2
AceFire6  1
AceFire6  3
Raknath   1
Raknath   1
```

and use your statement, the database will group all values for `AceFire6` that have a `kills` value of `2`, all values for `AceFire6` that have a `kills` value of `1`, etc. and then select the amount of kills.

So in the end, you will get this result:

```
AceFire6  3
AceFire6  2
AceFire6  1
Raknath   1
```

What you want is to sum the kills up, no matter how many the person had per - I assume - game.

For your second issue (the number of rows) see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select/2520377#2520377) answer of another question.

**Edit:**
Alright, something like this should work (no guarantees, I did not test the statement):

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, Name, kills
FROM (
  Select Name, sum(Kills) as kills from honscores group by Name order by Kills DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

Happy FPS-ing... :)

Comment: This worked exactly as I wanted it to :D Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// first query
SET @ranked = 0;
// second query
SELECT @ranked:=@ranked+1 ranked, name, kills FROM honscores 
GROUP BY name, kills 
ORDER BY ranked ASC;
```

And as [`@LeChe`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/437624/leche) saied you can use `SUM(kills)` in your field list to get the total kills for each name.

```
SELECT @ranked:=@ranked+1 ranked, 
       name, 
       SUM(kills) kills FROM honscores, (SELECT @ranked:=0) t2
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY ranked ASC;
```

Comment: I think that in his code, he will have problems with the `SET` before the actual `SELECT` - my guess is he wants one statement. :)