# find the position of a row in a query result

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that looks for videos with a certain `groupid` and returns the result. In this result I need to find the position of a certain `$vid_id`:

```
  function getGroupVidPos($id,$vid_id)
  {
    global $db;
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM videos WHERE `groupid`='$id' ORDER BY date DESC");
    $a = $db->fetch($result);
    return $a;
  }
```

Can I do this in the MySQL statement it self? Or better use `array_search`? Or any other ideas?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with `the position of`, do you need the record or its place in the result set?

Comment: @jeroen - it's place in the result set - the query returns i.e. 10 rows, I need to find out what position the $vid_id is in those...

Comment: you can generate row numbers. take a look at this article; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Comment: well, seems like a rather complicated way, isn't it?