# Retrieving rows from mySql Table using Groupby

Tags: asp.net, mysql, sql

I have a table

[image: Table]

I am using the following query

```
select max(dblVersion),sName,fCompleted,ixLastModifiedBy,dtCreatedAt,dtLastModifiedAt,fStatus from tblechecklisttemplateversion group by ixTemplate
```

I am getting the below table as output
[image: Table2]

The row values of other columns are not corresponding to the dblVersion Column .. How to display the corresponding row values

Comment: Not clear, what is the result expected ?

Comment: Try using `group by ixTemplate,dblVersion`

Comment: In Table2 the dtCreated should be 2012-04-05 02:57:36 and fstatus Should be 1 and dbLastModifiedat Should be 2012-04-05 02:57:36 .. Thus the corresponding column values are not displayed except for fCompleted=0 .. Compare the Table1 and Table2

Comment: @ M.S Nayak The result is same as Table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
   a.dblVersion,
   a.sName,
   a.fCompleted,
   a.ixLastModifiedBy,
   a.dtCreatedAt,
   a.dtLastModifiedAt,
   a.fStatus 
FROM 
   tblechecklisttemplateversion a
JOIN (
    SELECT 
        ixTemplate,
        max(dblVersion) as dblVersion 
    FROM 
        tblechecklisttemplateversion 
    GROUP BY 
        ixTemplate) as b
ON 
    a.ixTemplate=b.ixTemplate and a.dblVersion=b.dblVersion
```

Comment: it is giving an Error .. Column 'dblVersion'in field list is ambiguous.

Comment: Upss...  sorry. it's need `a` to avoid ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..

[MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

changed query -

```
  SELECT 0 INTO @x;
  select (@x:=@x+1) as  
  rownumber,max(dblVersion),sName,fCompleted,ixLastModifiedBy,dtCreatedAt,
  dtLastModifiedAt,fStatus 
  from tblechecklisttemplateversion group by ixTemplate
```

Comment: its Giving the same result as of earlier