# mysql query get specific record

Tags: mysql, position

Im doing a rankings table of sorts, and need to find a specific rows position from a query.

eg:
    SELECT name FROM players ORDER BY points DESC

How would I get the position of the record with the `name` field of 'John', or any other?

So I want the result to give me one number (the rank of 'John')

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2520377/1315604

Answer (score 1):

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, name 
  FROM players ORDER BY points DESC
```

or

```
SELECT @rn:=@rn+1 AS rank, name
FROM (
  SELECT name 
      FROM players ORDER BY points DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

Comment: This is a variable declaration syntax in mysql.

Comment: thanks, Im wanting to get a specific row though, like I want to find out what rank 'John' is, so it just returns a number.