# How to add ROW INDEX as a column to SQL SELECT query?

Tags: mysql, sql

Assume I've SQL query like this:

```
SELECT id, name, index(not a real column) FROM users ORDER BY rating DESC
```

I want to add column to selected columns that will represent the index of the record.

Example:

```
 id    name  rating
 1     a     4
 2     b     2
 3     c     8
 4     d     5
```

For this table I want to get:

```
 id    name  rating  index
 3     c     8       1
 4     d     5       2
 1     a     4       3
 2     b     2       4
```

Comment: so you want the row number within the result table?

Comment: Isn't something missing in the sentence that you briefly describe your requirement? "add column to selected columns..." NVM I got what you mean. You need row index number of the resulting table.

Comment: what is index of the record?

Comment: Yes.
(Apparently you can't answer yes or no, because there are a minimum of characters on this textarea)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Try the following to get the row_index:

```
set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT id,name,rating, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as row_index FROM users
ORDER BY rating desc;
```

Comment: It worked, but seems that there is not elegant solution for that.

Comment: How elegant you are looking for Yarin? :) I am also wondering what you meant by the "minimum of characters on this textarea"...

Comment: I was looking for something like INDEX() function.
As for the 'minimum' thing, it's relates to Stackoverflow validation on textarea when adding comments :P

Comment: Good one. :D on 'minimum note' . BTW usage of `INDEX()` in MySQL for your required context.......perhaps in the futures plans ;) IF you find one, I am interested too.

Comment: MySQL does not support analytic/"windowing"/OLAP-type functions, so this is as elegant as it gets! In Oracle or MS SQL-Server you could write: select id, name, rating, row_number () over (partition by id order by rating desc) "index" from users order by rating desc

Comment: But notice, this code is applied for native sql code. If you want to call a query in php, you should declare it as following:

Answer (score 3):

It's now builtin in MySQL 8.0 and MariaDB 10.2:

```
SELECT
  id, name, rating,
  ROW_NUMBER(ORDER BY rating DESC) AS index
FROM users ORDER BY rating DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a column to order by, you can still use `ROW_NUMBER()`:

```
SELECT 
  id, name, rating,
  ROW_NUMBER(ORDER BY (select 1)) AS index
FROM users
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like 
`set @cnt=0; select *, @cnt:=@cnt+1 from users order by rating desc;`

Should do the job (You'll need to set @cnt before each query though)

Answer (score 0):

@bonCodigo's answer is correct when you try in php admin or in sql code.
But if you want to call a query in php, you should declare it as follows:

```
$sql_query = "SELECT (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS 'row_index', id, name, rating FROM (SELECT @row_number:=0) AS temp, users"

$this->db->query ( $sql_query )->result ();
```

(This piece of code is for Code igniter framework)

**UPDATED:**

However, it won't work when using `JOIN` together. In this case, you need to read data as usual then add a column index by yourself, you can take an idea from this code:

```
$list = $this->db->query ( $sql_query )->result ();

for($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i++ ){
    $list[$i]->no = $i + 1;
}
```

(This piece of code is for Code igniter framework)