# mySQL trouble building query with multiple limits

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have this query which works with the single limit imposed at the end.

```
select distinct
    loc.mID,
    loc.city,
    loc.state,
    loc.zip,
    loc.country,
    loc.latitude,
    loc.longitude,
    baseInfo.firstname,
    baseInfo.lastname,
    baseInfo.profileimg,
    baseInfo.facebookID,
    (((acos(sin(('37.816876'*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(('37.816876'*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((('-121.285410' - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance`,
    teams.teamName,
    teams.leagueType,
    teams.teamType,
    teams.subcat
FROM memb_geo_locations loc
left join memb_friends friends on (friends.mID = loc.mID or friends.friendID = loc.mID) and (friends.mID = '100018' or friends.friendID = '100018')
join memb_baseInfo baseInfo on baseInfo.mID = loc.mID 
join memb_teams teams on teams.mID = loc.mID 
where 
    loc.primaryAddress = '1'
    and ((friends.mID is null or friends.friendID is null)
    or (friends.isactive = 2))
    and (
        teams.teamName like '%Anaheim Ducks%' 
        or teams.teamName like '%San Jose Sharks%' 
        or teams.teamName like '%New England Patriots%' 
        or teams.teamName like '%New York Yankees%' 
        or teams.teamName like '%Orlando Magic%'
        )
    and loc.mID != 100018 
    having `distance` < 50 
    order by baseInfo.firstname 
    asc limit 30
```

However I want my results to be limited by the teamName to 3 results max per, And I have tried stuff to the extent of

```
select distinct
    loc.mID,
    loc.city,
    loc.state,
    loc.zip,
    loc.country,
    loc.latitude,
    loc.longitude,
    baseInfo.firstname,
    baseInfo.lastname,
    baseInfo.profileimg,
    baseInfo.facebookID,
    (((acos(sin(('37.816876'*pi()/180)) * sin((`latitude`*pi()/180))+cos(('37.816876'*pi()/180)) * cos((`latitude`*pi()/180)) * cos((('-121.285410' - `longitude`)*pi()/180))))*180/pi())*60*1.1515) AS `distance`,
    teams.teamName,
    teams.leagueType,
    teams.teamType,
    teams.subcat
FROM memb_geo_locations loc
left join memb_friends friends on (friends.mID = loc.mID or friends.friendID = loc.mID) and (friends.mID = '100018' or friends.friendID = '100018')
join memb_baseInfo baseInfo on baseInfo.mID = loc.mID 
join memb_teams teams on teams.mID = loc.mID 
where 

    loc.primaryAddress = '1'
    and ((friends.mID is null or friends.friendID is null)
    or (friends.isactive = 2))

    and (
        (select * from memb_teams where teamName like '%Buffalo Bills%' limit 2),
        (select * from memb_teams where teamName like '%San Jose Sharks%' limit 2),
        (select * from memb_teams where teamName like '%New England Patriots%' limit 2)
        )

    and loc.mID != 100018 

having `distance` < 150 
order by baseInfo.firstname 
asc limit 30
```

With no success, usually just syntax errors.. or `Operand Should 1 Column(s)` so I am reaching out here hopefully someone can give me some idea how to refine my query a bit so I can limit the results to 3 per teamName.. rather than having staggered results where I could have 20 of one and 4 of another 2 of another and 1 and 1 (which is not desired). 3 or less per team is desired, Just don't know how. Ideas, that don't involve tackling a huge data set from the query and looping over it via server side code to output results I desire?

Comment: It doesn't make sense to put a `SELECT` in the `WHERE` clause like that, and I don't understand what you're trying to do by putting 3 of them separated by commas.

Comment: I'm not going to try to construct it myself, but here's what I think you need to do: write a subquery that generates per-team rank of each selected row (search for implementing rank in mysql), then filter that on `rank <= 3` in the main query.

Comment: See also this http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ and search for "mysql top n per group" in SO.

Comment: I'm going based on someone else's recommendation with the selects in the where. ultimately I am pooling data from all the above joins and everything else and when I run the first example I get results  based on order they are stored in the db, so if there's 15 results for one type in the db before the others and 10 of one of the others and 5 of another I end up with results sets that are bigger than I want for each type when all I want is 3 of each matching the rest of the params in the query

Answer (score 0):

IN MSSQL I use ROW_NUMBER function, and it would be something like this:

SELECT * FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE recno 
 IN (SELECT recno FROM (SELECT Teamname, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Teamname ORDER BY recno DESC) AS intRow FROM dbo.MyTable) AS T 
 WHERE intRow IN (1,2,3))

recno=your unique record number

Basically your Subquery selects the top 3 records, adding a new "ROW NUMBER" column.
The Top Query selects all the records with Rownumber between 1 to 3.

I know there is no ROW_NUMBER() native function in MYSQL, so you could use this instead:

[MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)