# Invert order of SQL subquery that uses row ranking

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by, subquery

I have a MySQL table which contains statistics about function usage for a program. What I retrieve from it basically looks like this (top 15 total here) :

```
SELECT function_id, data_timer, SUM( data_counter ) total 
FROM data
GROUP BY function_id 
ORDER BY total DESC

+-------------+------------+-------+
| function_id | data_timer | total |
+-------------+------------+-------+
|          56 |        567 |  4389 |
|          23 |       7880 |  1267 |
|           7 |        145 |   812 |
|         ... |        ... |   ... |
+-------------+------------+-------+
```

Since those results are used in a website module where the user can select which column will be used to ORDER BY as well as between ASC and DESC, I needed to retrieve the **rank** of each row of the results.

With the help of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select), I was able to assign a rank to each row of the results :

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, function_id, data_timer, SUM( data_counter ) total
FROM data 
WHERE client_id = 2 
GROUP BY function_id 
ORDER BY total DESC

+------+-------------+------------+-------+
| rank | function_id | data_timer | total |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+
|    1 |          56 |        567 |  4389 |
|    2 |          23 |       7880 |  1267 |
|    3 |           7 |        145 |   812 |
|  ... |         ... |        ... |   ... |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+
```

I am now having some difficulties trying to invert this table, meaning I would like to have the results sorted with the least used function first. Something like this (supposing there are 76 functions) :

```
+------+-------------+------------+-------+
| rank | function_id | data_timer | total |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+
|   76 |          44 |        346 |     1 |
|   75 |           2 |       3980 |     4 |
|   74 |          13 |        612 |     7 |
|  ... |         ... |        ... |   ... |
+------+-------------+------------+-------+
```

Here is my SQL query attempt :

```
SELECT rank, function_id, data_timer, total
FROM
(
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, function_id, data_timer, SUM( data_counter ) total
FROM data 
WHERE client_id = 2 
GROUP BY function_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
)
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

It keeps popping me this :

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that 
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'SET @rank = 0' at line 4
```

Since I'm not too skilled with SQL, I guess I'm missing something obvious.

Any help will be gladly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: If you're ordering by total DESC, inverting would be ordering by total ASC, no?  Why use the sub-query?

Comment: "*I would like to have the results sorted with the least used function first.*"  What represents this value? `SUM(data_counter)', something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a variable inside of your sub-query.  This won't work.  Move the assignment outside of your sub-query and it should run.

```
SET @rank = 0;
SELECT rank, function_id, data_timer, total
FROM
(
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, function_id, data_timer, SUM( data_counter ) total
FROM data 
WHERE client_id = 2 
GROUP BY function_id 
ORDER BY total DESC
)
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something obvious, haha. Thanks for the fast reply!

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to initialize your `@rank` variable in your query instead of a separate statement:

```
SELECT rank, function_id, data_timer, total
FROM
(
    SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, function_id, data_timer, SUM( data_counter ) total
    FROM data, 
        (SELECT @rank := 0 ) r
    WHERE client_id = 2 
    GROUP BY function_id 
    ORDER BY total DESC
) r
ORDER BY rank DESC
```

- [Condensed SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f2ced/5)

Comment: That does not work, the whole rank column is filled with NULL values.

Comment: @AlexisLeclerc -- I edited the answer (I left out a colon) -- anyhow, glad you got it working...