# Displaying row number in mysql

Tags: mysql, row-number

I have user table like this .also following 2 fields are fixed . userId is primary key.

```
userId    name
898        abc
900        xyz
902        rrr
904        wer
```

if i fetch particular `userid` then result should display as row number.
for example `userid` `902` then result should display `3`.

how to write SQL query?

Comment: added my answer below

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Get row number on select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
    SET @a:=0;

    SELECT  @a:=@a+1 serial_number, 
          userId, name 
    FROM users;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cad2bc/5)

**N.B-** Although you should add a PK as auto increment to the table not just to get the serial number but to add index to your table to fetch the records faster

Comment: it returns always 1.      SELECT  @a:=@a+1 serial_number, 
        userId, name 
FROM    users,
        (SELECT @a:= 0) AS a where userId=902;    It should return 3

Comment: that is not supposed to return the serial_number while comparing a particular id.....

Comment: because we are just adding the serial_number to the output of the query...what you want will need an extra column in database which you dont want

Comment: i've been searching high and low for a simple answer to this, and this works beautifully. upvoted, thanks a ton!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set @row_num = 0; 
SELECT user_id,name, @row_num := @row_num + 1 as index FROM tablename
ORDER BY user_id desc;
```

Comment: @ahamedsakir I had made some changes on the answer. Try this. This may helps you

Answer (score -1):

The easier way out.

```
$row_number = 1;
$sql = "SELECT column1, column2 ORDER BY column1";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sq1);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{

echo "<tr><td>".$row_number++."</td><td>".$row['0']."</td><td>".$row['1']."</td> 
</tr>";
}
```