# Gettin NULL value when numbering SQL tuples from SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select, row-number

I need to get a progressive number next on each row out of my SELECT query.

i.e. Query result without numbering:

```
user_id
paola
Carla
Marta
```

what i want is

```
number user_id
1      paola
2      Carla
3      Marta
```

I am aware that the problem is very similar to the one in

[MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2520357/3008431)

And on the first query the code suggested in the answers seems to work for me too BUT when I recall the query, or when i try to export the results, i get a NULL value in the column where the row number is supposed to be.

Do you know why?
Did I do something wrong in the variable instance?

The code I use is the following:

```
set @x=0;

SELECT @x:=@x + 1 AS row_index, user_id FROM TABLE ORDER BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct.  My guess is that you have a typo, so the variable being set is not the same as the variable being incremented.

By the way, these can be combined into a single statement:

```
SELECT @x:=@x + 1 AS row_index, user_id
FROM TABLE cross join
     (select @x := 0) const
ORDER BY user_id;
```

That is, the `select` can actually initialize the variable.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 SELECT @x:=@x + 1 AS row_index, user_id FROM 
      ( SELECT row_index , user_id from TABLE ORDER BY user_id ) t1 , 
      (SELECT @x:=0) t2;
```