# Count users from 1 with users from MySQL server

Tags: php

I have a user table in the admin panel that will echo all users to a table, but in the first row of the table I want to echo the number they are so you can easily just scroll to the bottom and find how many users there are, so I want the format to be like this..

**#Number | User**

```
    1 | ImSchnebz<br>
    2 | etc...<br>
    3 | etc...
```

Comment: add a counter and start display it inside the loop and increment it !!

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yeah I figured out that already, the thing is, I have no clue on how to do it..

Comment: I think you can find the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT @cont := @cont +1, username from tableName
```