# How to get rank in MySQL from 2 tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

I have 2 different tables in my database by the name of: rank, settings.

Here is how each table looks like with a few records in them:

### Table #rank:

```
id  points userid
--  ----- ------
 1    500      1
 2    300      2    
 3    900      3
 4   1500      4
 5    100      5
 6    700      6
 7    230      7
 8    350      8
 9    850      9
10    150     10
```

### Table #settings:

```
userid    active 
------    ------
     1         0
     2         1
     3         1
     4         1
     5         1
     6         0
     7         1
     8         1
     9         0
    10         1
```

I want to get the rank of a specific user by `user_id` from the `rank` table ordering by their points. Also I would Only want to include the users in the ranking results, if they have `active = 1` set in the `settings` table.

I have a simple ranking query, but it is not really effective, because it does include everyone even if the user is not active:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(SELECT @sort:=@sort+1 AS sort, points, userid
 FROM rank,
(SELECT @sort := 0) s 
 ORDER BY points DESC) t 
WHERE userid= 8
```

Any idea, how could I achieve my goals here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few sub queries. First gets all the users who are active in the right order. That is used as a source for another query to add the rank. Then this is used as the source for the points and rank for the userid you are actually interested in

```
SELECT sort, points
FROM
(
    SELECT @sort:=@sort + 1 AS sort, points, userid
    FROM
    (
        SELECT rank.points, rank.userid
        FROM rank
        INNER JOIN settings
        ON rank.userid = settings.userid
        WHERE settings.active = 1
        ORDER BY points DESC
    ) sub0
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @sort:=0) sub2
) sub1
WHERE sub1.userid = 8
```

Comment: Oops, missed one (for the cross joined sub query to initialise the @sort variable). Now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing the idea from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4474389/92063

```
SELECT 
    @rn:=@rn+1 AS RANK
    ,USER_ID
    ,POINTS
FROM (
    SELECT
        R.userid AS USER_ID
        ,R.points AS POINTS
    FROM
        rank R
    INNER JOIN
        settings S
        ON R.userid = S.userid
    WHERE
        S.active = 1
    ORDER BY
        R.points DESC
) t1, (SELECT @rn:=0) t2;
```

Comment: This is actually not really what I'm looking for because I need only the actual user's row, not all of them.