# Sqlite get ROW NUMBER and COUNT of records found on every SELECT request

Tags: sql, sqlite

I´m using Sqlite3 on a grid application pretty much like that [post here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940884/sql-get-row-number-and-count-on-every-select-request).

The grid needs the rows that is being show and the total number of rows found, used for paging.

On Oracle I use the following statement to get rows from 100 to 500 - fields Id, Name, Phone where Deleted=false:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() 
              OVER (ORDER BY ID)  AS RN, 
              COUNT(*) OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) AS CNT) 
              Id, Name, Phone FROM MyTable WHERE Deleted='F') 
T WHERE RN > 100 AND RN < 500;
```

On MySQl, I normally use the excellet `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS` followed by a `SELECT FOUND_ROWS()` call.

So my questions are:

a) Is there any equivalent of this Sqlite3 for either Oracle or MySQL option above ?
b) How can I accomplish that on Sqlite3 without issuing 2 selects (one for querying and another one for counting) ?

The question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records) does not solve my problem because it does not return the number of records, just pages through the table.

Thanks a lot for helping...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient paging in SQLite with millions of records](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14468586/efficient-paging-in-sqlite-with-millions-of-records)

Comment: That does not solve my problem because it does not return the total number of records found... That´s why I´m using the `OVER` and the `SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`  mechanism.

Comment: SQLite doesn't support window queries. You can't really get the count without a separate query, or by counting the rows yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In recent versions of SQLite (3.25.0 and later) there is support for [window functions](https://www.sqlite.org/windowfunctions.html). So you can rewrite your query as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS RN, 
               COUNT() OVER () AS CNT,
               Id, Name, Phone FROM MyTable WHERE Deleted='F') 
T WHERE RN > 100 AND RN < 500;
```

Comment: SQLite 3.25 OS support: Android 11 (API level 30) (SQLite 3.28) ; iOS 13.0 (SQLite 3.28.0) ; Sadly this means you can't use this on e.g. Android 7 :/

Comment: What worked for me on Android 7 was a basic subquery `someId, someOtherColumn, (SELECT COUNT(someId) FROM yourTableNameGoesHere) AS c` @Altair7852 do you know any advantage of using `OVER()` window over this?