# SQL query interleaving two different statuses

Tags: sql

I have a table testtable having fields

```
Id    Name       Status
1     John       active
2     adam       active
3     cristy    incative
4     benjamin  inactive
5     mathew    active
6     thomas    inactive
7     james     active
```

I want a query that should dispaly the reuslt like

```
Id    Name       Status

1     John       active
3     cristy    incative
2     adam       active
4     benjamin  inactive
5     mathew    active
6     thomas    inactive
7     james     active
```

my question is how to take records in the order of active status then inactive then active then inactive etc.. like that from this table.

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you tried?

Comment: Why id 2 was adam and suddenly became cristy? What if there is 10 active users and 2 inactive?

Comment: @Elhana,@Renier,@Madhivanan   my question is how to take records in the order of active status then inactive then active then inactive etc.. like that from this table..

Comment: It looks like homework question, nevertheless a hint: 2 queries manipulating rownum to return even and odd numbers in union, then wrap it with select order by rownum

Comment: @Elhana  if there is 10 active users and 2 inactive,then the list should be active,inactive,acitve,inactive,active,active,active,active etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query sorts on interleaved active/inactive state:

```
SELECT [id], 
       [name], 
       [status] 
FROM   (
           (
             SELECT
                Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS RowNo, 
                0 AS sorter, 
                [id], 
                [name], 
                [status] 
             FROM   testtable 
             WHERE  [status] = 'active'
           ) 
           UNION ALL 
           (
             SELECT
                Row_number() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS RowNo, 
                1 AS sorter, 
                [id], 
                [name], 
                [status] 
             FROM   testtable 
             WHERE  [status] = 'inactive'
           )
       ) innerUnion 
ORDER  BY ( RowNo * 2 + sorter )
```

This approach uses an inner UNION on two SELECT statements, one which returns active rows, the other inactive rows. They both have a RowNumber generated, which is later multiplied by two to ensure it's always even. There's a sorter column that's just a bit field, and to ensure that a unique number is available for sorting: adding it to the RowNumber yields either an odd or even number depending on active/inactive state, hence allowing the results to be interleaved.

The SQL Fiddle link is here, to allow testing and manipulation: 
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8a8a1/11/0

In the absence of a specified DB system, I've assumed that SQL Server 2008 (or newer) is being used. An alternate row numbering system would be necessary on other DBMSes.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i got the answer

```
SET @rank=0;
SET @rank1=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank,id,name,status FROM `testtablejohn` where status='E'
UNION
SELECT @rank1:=@rank1+1 AS rank,id,name,status FROM `testtablejohn` where status='D'
order by rank
```

Comment: Now you only need to implement the even/odd numbering scheme and you are there. Just start `@rank` at -1 and add +2 to `@rank` and `@rank1` on every row.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post any example of what you tried so far, I will limit my answer to the general approach as well.

One approach could be to generate a row number for `active` rows and a row number for `inactive` rows. Start your numbering for `active` at 1 and use only odd numbers (that means increase your counter by 2 every time) and do the same thing with 2 and even numbers for the `inactive` rows. Put those two counters in the same column.

You will end up with a single column to easily sort on in your `ORDER BY` clause.

Here are some links that might be useful for you:
[MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-case-statement/

Just give it a go with those. If you can't make it work, then show us what you tried so far. Post some example code in the question and we might be able to guide you!