# Return Asc Increment After Sort MYSQL

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to have asc index number/serial number after order by price. that mean i want the highest amount be the first row, then the serial number for it is 1, and etc.

```
serial number |  products  |  price
1                A            10000
2                C            4000
3                B            20
4                D            10
```

i tried these:

//1st trial

```
select COALESCE((id) + 0, 0) as serial
```

//2nd trial

```
SELECT  @s:=@s+1 serial_number,student_id,student_name,student_avg
FROM    students,
    (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
WHERE
student_avg > 4;
```

both give me serial number not from 1 - n, it's messed up.

FYI: im using laravel 4.2

Comment: What? The query doesn't even match the table/results you're describing (students? products?) Please clarify your question and show the results of the queries so we can see what's not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Answer (score 1):

You should decide what is your question about? about `students` or about `products`? :-) Apples or Oranges? :-)

I've chosen product part:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe0f2/2

```
SET @idx=0;

SELECT * , @idx:=@idx+1 `idx`
FROM products
ORDER BY price desc
```

Comment: I debated upvoting because I wanted the student version. ;P Nice answer!

Answer (score 0):

your 2nd trial is close

```
SELECT @s:=@s+1 serial_number,student_id,student_name,student_avg
FROM students
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @s:= 0) AS s
WHERE student_avg > 4;
```

BTW, this is pure mysql query, nothing to do with laravel