# Retrieving a row number from within a specific group of rows using a self join in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, self-join

Given a table named `rating` in a MySQL database.

```sql
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| rating_id   | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| prod_id     | bigint(20) unsigned | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| rating_num  | int(10) unsigned    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ip_address  | varchar(45)         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| row_version | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I need to fetch a row number from within a group of rows in this table. In Oracle, the `row_number()` window function is the rescue.

```sql
SELECT row_num 
  FROM  (SELECT row_number() over (PARTITION BY prod_id ORDER BY rating_id DESC)
         AS prod_id, rating_id, row_num FROM rating)
WHERE rating_id=? AND prod_id = ?;
```

Neither JPA nor MySQL however, supports window functions. Therefore, the following different SQL statement can be used (self join based on `prod_id`).

```sql
SELECT a.prod_id, a.rating_id, count(*) as row_number 
FROM rating a 
INNER JOIN rating b ON a.prod_id = b.prod_id AND a.rating_id <= b.rating_id
GROUP BY a.prod_id, a.rating_id
ORDER BY a.prod_id, a.rating_id DESC
```

The statement returns the following result set.

```sql
+---------+-----------+------------+
| prod_id | rating_id | row_number |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       7 |        16 |          1 |
|       7 |         3 |          2 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       8 |         8 |          1 |
|       8 |         1 |          2 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|       9 |        15 |          1 |
|       9 |        14 |          2 |
|       9 |         5 |          3 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|      10 |        11 |          1 |
|      10 |        10 |          2 |
|      10 |         9 |          3 |
|      10 |         7 |          4 |
|      10 |         6 |          5 |
|      10 |         2 |          6 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
|      16 |        13 |          1 |
|      16 |        12 |          2 |
|      16 |         4 |          3 |
+---------+-----------+------------+
```

A row number associated with a particular group of products can be retrieved from the above result set based on `rating_id` (primary key) using an additional condition in the join. The query can now be completed fully as follows.

```sql
SELECT a.prod_id, a.rating_id, count(*) as row_number 
FROM rating a 
INNER JOIN rating b ON a.prod_id = b.prod_id AND a.rating_id <= b.rating_id
AND a.rating_id=?
GROUP BY a.prod_id, a.rating_id
ORDER BY a.prod_id, a.rating_id DESC
```

As obvious, a row number of a specific group of products can now be selected from the third column (`row_number`) of the result set (which will always be one row only).

---

The finalized query in JPA is nevertheless still troublesome. The following criteria query is insufficient to generate the above SQL statement.

```java
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<Tuple> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createTupleQuery();
Root<Rating> root = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(Rating.class));
criteriaQuery.multiselect(root.get(Rating_.product).get(Product_.prodId), root.get(Rating_.ratingId), criteriaBuilder.count(root));

Join<Rating, Rating> join = root.join(Rating_.rating, JoinType.INNER).on(criteriaBuilder.equal(root, rating));
criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(Rating_.ratingId), join.get(Rating_.ratingId)));
criteriaQuery.groupBy(root.get(Rating_.product).get(Product_.prodId), root.get(Rating_.ratingId));
criteriaQuery.orderBy(criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(Rating_.product).get(Product_.prodId)), criteriaBuilder.desc(root.get(Rating_.ratingId)));

List<Tuple> list = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getResultList();
Long rowNumber = list == null || list.isEmpty() ? 0L : list.get(0).get(2, Long.class);
```

The JPQL corresponding to the above criteria query :

```sql
SELECT a.product.prodId, a.ratingId, COUNT(a) AS row_number
FROM Rating a INNER JOIN a.rating b ON a.ratingId=:ratingId
WHERE a.ratingId <= b.ratingId
GROUP BY a.product.prodId, a.ratingId
ORDER BY a.product.prodId, a.ratingId DESC
```

Both of the above queries generate the following SQL statement.

```sql
select
    rating0_.`prod_id` as col_0_0_,
    rating0_.`rating_id` as col_1_0_,
    count(rating0_.`rating_id`) as col_2_0_ 
from
    `jboss_projectdb`.`rating` rating0_ 
inner join
    `jboss_projectdb`.`rating` rating1_ 
        on rating0_.`prod_id`=rating1_.`rating_id` 
        and (
            rating0_.`rating_id`=?
        ) 
where
    rating0_.`rating_id`<=rating1_.`rating_id` 
group by
    rating0_.`prod_id` ,
    rating0_.`rating_id` 
order by
    rating0_.`prod_id` desc,
    rating0_.`rating_id` desc
```

Notice the join condition in the generated statement.

```sql
on rating0_.`prod_id`=rating1_.`rating_id`
```

It should however be

```sql
on rating0_.`prod_id`=rating1_.`prod_id`
```

So, the question being is how to self join the `rating` table based on `prod_id` (which is a foreign key)?

---

The self join relationship in the `Rating` entity has been defined as follows.

```java
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Rating rating;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "rating")
private List<Rating> ratingList;
```

I am not interested in using the following very MySQL specific statement to fetch a row number from inside a specific group of rows.

```sql
SELECT
    row_num 
FROM
    (SELECT @row_num := @row_num + 1 AS row_num, tbl.rating_id 
     FROM
         rating tbl, (SELECT @row_num := 0) t 
     WHERE
         tbl.prod_id=? 
     ORDER  BY
         tbl.rating_id DESC) t 
     WHERE
         rating_id = ?
```

---

**Update :**

If the relationship is changed like the following,

```java
@JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", referencedColumnName = "prod_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private Rating rating;

@JoinColumn(name = "prod_id", referencedColumnName = "prod_id")
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Rating> ratingList;
```

Hibernate throws the following exception.

```java
16:43:52,609 WARNING [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.lifecycle] (default task-18) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: entity.Rating[ratingId=null], for class: entity.Rating: service.app.exception.impl.DatabaseException: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: entity.Rating[ratingId=null], for class: entity.Rating
    at service.ejb.interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.handle(ExceptionInterceptor.java:32)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor398.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceLifecycleMethodInterceptor.java:89)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.ExecutionTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(ExecutionTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.SBInvocationInterceptor.processInvocation(SBInvocationInterceptor.java:47)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.weld.ejb.AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.aroundInvoke(AbstractEJBRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.processInvocation(EjbRequestScopeActivationInterceptor.java:83)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.concurrent.ConcurrentContextInterceptor.processInvocation(ConcurrentContextInterceptor.java:45)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InitialInterceptor.processInvocation(InitialInterceptor.java:21)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.processInvocation(ComponentDispatcherInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.pool.PooledInstanceInterceptor.processInvocation(PooledInstanceInterceptor.java:51)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInOurTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:275)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:327)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.processInvocation(CurrentInvocationContextInterceptor.java:41)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.invocationmetrics.WaitTimeInterceptor.processInvocation(WaitTimeInterceptor.java:43)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.AuthorizationInterceptor.processInvocation(AuthorizationInterceptor.java:138)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:100)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.ShutDownInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(ShutDownInterceptorFactory.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.LoggingInterceptor.processInvocation(LoggingInterceptor.java:66)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.NamespaceContextInterceptor.processInvocation(NamespaceContextInterceptor.java:50)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.component.interceptors.AdditionalSetupInterceptor.processInvocation(AdditionalSetupInterceptor.java:54)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.processInvocation(ContextClassLoaderInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:636)
    at org.jboss.invocation.AccessCheckingInterceptor.processInvocation(AccessCheckingInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.run(InterceptorContext.java:356)
    at org.jboss.invocation.PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.processInvocation(PrivilegedWithCombinerInterceptor.java:80)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewService$View.invoke(ViewService.java:195)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ViewDescription$1.processInvocation(ViewDescription.java:185)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.ChainedInterceptor.processInvocation(ChainedInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ProxyInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyInvocationHandler.java:73)
    at shareable.bean.ShareableService$$$view330.findRatingById(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:436)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:127)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:67)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:100)
    at shareable.bean.ShareableService$614900122$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.findRatingById(Unknown Source)
    at converter.RatingConverter.getAsObject(RatingConverter.java:41)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlBasicInputRenderer.getConvertedValue(HtmlBasicInputRenderer.java:171)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.getConvertedValue(UIViewParameter.java:437)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:975)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1248)
    at javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:712)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewParameter.processValidators(UIViewParameter.java:278)
    at org.omnifaces.component.input.ViewParam.processValidators(ViewParam.java:120)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1261)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1195)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.websockets.jsr.JsrWebSocketFilter.doFilter(JsrWebSocketFilter.java:129)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.filterExtensionLess(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:128)
    at org.omnifaces.facesviews.FacesViewsForwardingFilter.doFilter(FacesViewsForwardingFilter.java:89)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at filter.NoCacheFilter.doFilter(NoCacheFilter.java:33)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:122)
    at org.omnifaces.filter.HttpFilter.doFilter(HttpFilter.java:108)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.DisableCacheHandler.handleRequest(DisableCacheHandler.java:33)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationConstraintHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationConstraintHandler.java:51)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityConstraintHandler.java:56)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:284)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:263)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:174)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:793)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: entity.Rating[ratingId=null], for class: entity.Rating
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1692)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.convert(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1602)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:492)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.criteria.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getResultList(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:50)
    at shareable.bean.ShareableBean.findRatingById(ShareableBean.java:472)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.processInvocation(ManagedReferenceMethodInterceptor.java:52)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.doMethodInterception(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:82)
    at org.jboss.as.weld.ejb.Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.processInvocation(Jsr299BindingsInterceptor.java:93)
    at org.jboss.as.ee.component.interceptors.UserInterceptorFactory$1.processInvocation(UserInterceptorFactory.java:63)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:340)
    at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext$Invocation.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:437)
    at service.ejb.interceptors.ExceptionInterceptor.handle(ExceptionInterceptor.java:22)
    ... 133 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: entity.Rating[ratingId=null], for class: entity.Rating
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2146)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1132)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:306)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:2197)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:60)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.EntityLoader.loadByUniqueKey(EntityLoader.java:143)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2146)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:685)
    at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:427)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:151)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.initializeEntitiesAndCollections(Loader.java:1132)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:992)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:930)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:336)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2610)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2593)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2422)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2417)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:501)
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:371)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:216)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1339)
    at org.hibernate.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:606)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.internal.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:483)
    ... 148 more
```

`criteriaQuery.multiselect(...).distinct(true);`does not help. So, I don't think there may exist a way to get around the problem.

Comment: Why not a [native query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select) ?

Comment: In order to utilize the object model which it stands for, the use of native queries should be minimized as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate does everything exactly as what your mappings tell it to do. The construct `FROM Rating a INNER JOIN a.rating b` means join primary key of one rating with the foreign key (referencing that PK) of another.

To achieve what you want with your mappings you have to explicitly construct the join condition, so the `from` and `where` clauses of your JPQL could look like:

```
SELECT ...
FROM Rating a, Rating b
WHERE a.rating.id = b.rating.id
  AND a.ratingId = :ratingId
  AND a.ratingId <= b.ratingId
GROUP BY ...
ORDER BY ...
```

`rating.id` is translated to `prod_id` column.

Comment: I see Hibernate producing a cross join between tables being joined.

Comment: @Tiny Yes, isn't it what you want? To self-join the table on `prod_id`?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM table_a a, table_b b WHERE a.id = b.id` is considered to be an implicit inner join in RDBMS. This is equivalent to `SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id = b.id` (ANSI). Hibernate is expected to produce an inner join in this case. It appears to be a Hibernate's fault.

Comment: @Tiny No, it's not Hibernate fault, navigation path implicit joins (like `a.rating b`) work by joining primary key with foreign key, not two primary keys.