# How do I use row_number (or anything with same behavior) with Hibernate Criteria API?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, window-functions, criteria-api

I want to implement a similar query with CriteriaBuilder API:

```sql
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY Student_Score) AS RowNumberRank
FROM StudentScore
```

The main problem is that JPQL doesn't support window functions and I don't know how to replicate their behavior...

Comment: I know that it is possible with a native query but it is a pretty crooked solution...

Comment: You don't. As you stated, a native query is your only solution, as criteria API only provides general functions that all database systems have in common, like joins, where clause, sum, avg, etc. Vendor specific functions are not supported

Comment: I've seen that [some use cases of window functions can be rewritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961996/retrieving-a-row-number-from-within-a-specific-group-of-rows-using-a-self-join-i), but I'm not sure how I can convert my query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Analytical functions are vendor specific. This makes is hard to implement with a CriteriaBuilder API. Using native query ties your java application to a specific database vendor.
To avoid that you can create a vendor specific view and create in your java application a select with the criteria api using that view.

Beside the `StudentScore` entity you already have you had to define a (readonly) `StudentScoreView` entity with the extra attribute `rowNumberRand` which you can use in your JPQL query.