# MYSQL Update Based On A Row Index Equaling An ID In Another Table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, mysql-variables

I have two tables. I'd like to update a row in table1 based on the same row index in table2. The IDs don't match but but the ID in table 2 matches the row index. There will always be more data in table 2, but I don't care if the extra rows are missed.

How would I achieve this in a mysql UPDATE statement?

```
   table 1      ______________      table 2     _____________
   Row number  |  id  | value |    Row number | id  | value |
               |--------------|               |-----|-------|
        1      |  2   |   A   |        1      |  1  |   W   |
        2      |  4   |   B   |        2      |  2  |   X   |
        3      |  6   |   C   |        3      |  3  |   Y   |
                                       4      |  4  |   Z   |

  to:
    table 1      ______________    
    Row number |  id  | value |   
               |--------------|   
        1      |  2   |   W   |   
        2      |  4   |   X   |  
        3      |  6   |   Y   |
```

Comment: "the row index" -  What's that then?

Comment: `Row number` based on what sort order?

Comment: The row number in the table. I.e. the first row row[0], or the second row row[1].

Comment: @1000111 Clearly not. Otherwise the result would be W X Y ;-)

Comment: @tim_barber_7BB Rows in RDBMS tables represent unordered sets. So 'row index' or 'row number' has no meaning

Comment: Take ID to be the primary key and ordered ascending.

Comment: Got it after having a close look @Strawberry.  Your expected output doesn't make sense -- to the PO.

Comment: You can use left or right joins. Firstly, its better to use / set foreign keys otherwise it tends to become confusing. Secondly, you can use the select statement for fetching multiple values of one table with id of another table.

Comment: The expected answer makes sense: the requirement is for `table 1` to be updated where its ordinal row number matched the id value in `table 2`. The ordinal row number is found by counting rows when sorted by `id asc`. The row numbers for the other tables aren't required.

Comment: I take that back. The expected answer doesn't make sense... the output should be W,X,Y, not X,Y,Z (but the numbering in the question starting at 1 doesn't match the comment which suggests starting at 0)

Comment: @ChrisLear you're right. I've updated the expected answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, but it's not pretty.

```
set @c=0;
update t1
join (
    select tx.id,t2.value
    from t2
    join (
        select @c:=@c+1 as rownum, value, id
        from (
            select * from t1  order by id
        ) t3
    ) tx
    on t2.id=tx.rownum) tupdate
on t1.id = tupdate.id
set t1.value=tupdate.value;
```

The basic point behind it is to use a variable to count rows, then use that to join. I ended up using multiple nested selects because the requirement is to update t1 but only after making a version of it with the rows counted.

The `set` at the start is required to stop it from overcounting if repeated. See [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select) for the inspiration.