# Select rank of a specific player sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, ranking

I'm trying to make a query and I already searched for an answer on stackof but didn't find one matching my needs.
I have a table named player in which there are two columns, "nickname" and "score".
I use this query to get the top 5 players:

```
SELECT nickname, score
FROM player 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5;
```

and I got this as the answer:

```
nickname - score:    
zod      - 30  
ciao     - 20  
jiji     - 20  
mayina   - 20      
jon      - 0.
```

Now, I'd like to have the rank of a single player, let's say "jiji" and get 3 as a result, because it's the third result in the list.

I tried many queries like

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank 
FROM player
WHERE score >= (SELECT score FROM player WHERE nickname = 'jiji')
```

but they always return 4 for "jiji" or "ciao", which is the rank of the last player who gets 20 as score in that table.

How can I get to have 3 for "jiji", instead? Thank you very much.

Comment: Please be careful when tagging your questions. This is clearly mysql and not sql-server. These are NOT the same thing.

Comment: You need to use analytical function to solve ur problem

Comment: look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Comment: @Teja what do you mean by that?

Comment: Jiji is joint second

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using commonly used definitions, the *rank* for `jiji` would be:

```
SELECT count(*) + 1 AS rank 
FROM player
WHERE score > (SELECT score FROM player WHERE nickname = 'jiji');
```

This returns "2", because there are ties when score = 30.

If you want the rank to be stable and different for each row, you need an additional key.  An obvious key (in this case) is `nickname`:

```
SELECT count(*)  AS rank 
FROM player p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT score FROM player WHERE nickname = 'jiji') s
WHERE p.score > s.score or
      (p.score = s.score and p.nickname <= 'jiji');
```

Comment: This actually is what I was trying to do (thank you) but I just noticed that phpmyadmin doesn't order also per alphabetical order of the key (nickname) when I do the first query.
So.. How can I get this `SELECT nickname, score
FROM player 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5` query to also order by the nickname alphabetical order? I tried something but nothing worked. (I'm a bit confused 'cause it's been hours since I'm trying to get over this, sorry..)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1, nickname, score 
    FROM player 
    ORDER BY score 
    DESC) AS t
WHERE t.nickname = 'jiji';
```

Correct comment about this not being stable in case of score ties. To make it stable, we can change the sorting to be based on score and then nickname:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT @rank:=@rank+1, nickname, score 
    FROM player 
    ORDER BY score, nickname 
    DESC) AS t
WHERE t.nickname = 'jiji';
```

Comment: I just came up with the same query before checking on here again and this works (thanks!)
But now as I'm using this on php, I have to make two separate queries, one for the `set @rank=0` and the other for the rest.
And trying to do so with the second query it tells me:  
"Error. Unknown column 'rank' in 'field list'

Comment: The code I'm using:  
`$querysetRank = "set @rank = 0";
if ($result = mysqli_query($database, $querysetRank))
{
      $queryPlayerRank = "SELECT rank FROM (SELECT @rank:=rank+1 as rank, nickname FROM player order by score desc) as pl where pl.nickname = '$nickname'";
      if (!($resultZ = mysqli_query($database, $queryPlayerRank)))
                    //error
      else
             //do things`

Comment: @JulsA I think you need to make sure both queries run from the same session, so `@rank` is available in the second query.

Comment: @JulsA - I am not a php expert. This may require another question (or there may be existing questions you can find(

Comment: As a note:  This answer is not *stable*, because sorting in relational databases in not stable.  That means that when there are ties, the rank for a given row could vary between runs of the query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - Correct. Edited

Comment: How to use `SET @rank=0;` in PHP