# Efficient way to select number of row in sorted result set (MySQL)

Tags: mysql

A MySQL table looks like this:

```
Item  Score
-----------
A     3.646
B     2.775
C     6.383
D     0.122
...
```

There is an index on column `Score`. I want to select items in the order of descending score, and I also want to know the rank of an item (i.e. the number of that particular row in the result set). In this example, the desired result would be:

```
Item  Rank
----------
C     1
A     2
B     3
D     4
```

Is there an efficient way to do this on big tables? I would like to avoid sub-selects if possible.

P.S.: yes, the rank in the result set will of course always be 1, 2, 3, ... but no, I cannot just derive this in the application because these results will be further processed within the DB and not returned to the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SET @rank=0;
SELECT Item, @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```

This option uses a session variable to emulate row number functionality, as MySQL does not support analytic functions.

Here is a [link to a helpful tutorial](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-row_number/) which discusses emulating row number in MySQL in more depth.

Comment: @sumit Actually, many other people [beat both of us to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select) :-)

Comment: Feels embarrassing if it's really that simple :) I was thinking much too complicated... and I didn't know that the additions would happen after the `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 2):

Single statement answer is:

```
select
    item,
    @rank := @rank + 1 rank
from (
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY Score DESC
) t cross join (select @rank:=0) t2
```

Without subquery:

```
SELECT Item, @rank := if(@rank is null, 1, @rank+1) AS rank
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY Score DESC;
```