# phymyadmin add row number in query result

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Hi i have this sql code i want to query in phpmyadmin

```
SELECT DISTINCT `unit`,`location` FROM `myasset` ORDER BY `unit` asc
```

It is possible to add custom number in my sql result

I tried something like below..its not working ..i received message row_number function does not exist

```
  SELECT DISTINCT Row_Number(),`unit`,`location` FROM `myasset` ORDER BY `unit` 



 SELECT Row_Number() DISTINCT`unit`,`location` FROM `myasset` ORDER BY `unit`
```

Comment: Why do you need that custom number?

Comment: If you are using MySQL then you get the error message because `ROW_NUMBER` does not exist in MySQL. You can use variables instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Comment: you can use variable like this select @rownum:=@rownum+1 No,`unit`,`location` FROM `myasset` , (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY `unit` ;

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
select @rownum:=@rownum+1 No,DISTINCT unit,location FROM myasset ORDER BY unit, (SELECT @rownum:=0);
```

Comment: Static analysis:

4 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "No" at position 26)
Unexpected token. (near "," at position 28)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "DISTINCT" at position 29)
Unexpected token. (near "unit" at position 38)

Comment: remove r from the end

Answer (score 0):

First you have to set a value like

SET @rnum = 0;

then

SELECT @rnum:=@rnum+1 AS row_num, DISTINCT `unit`,`location` FROM `myasset` ORDER BY `unit` asc

Hope it will solve your issue.

Thanks

Comment: I received this error Static analysis:

3 errors were found during analysis.

An expression was expected. (near "DISTINCT" at position 34)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "DISTINCT" at position 34)
Unexpected token. (near "unit" at position 43)

Comment: Please copy paste to a notepad and try again.