# How to add rank for each row in mysql view

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this view my mysql database

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS time_all;
CREATE VIEW `time_all` AS
SELECT `scans`.`datetime` FROM `time_clock`.`scans`
ORDER BY `scans`.`datetime` ASC;
```

I want to add unique rank value for each row in this view, can anyone tell me how to do that?

Comment: MySQL <> sql-server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Comment: @Ali No, I tried that before, it's not working for view

Comment: @D.Kenny YES you're right

Comment: As others have suggested, first figure out which RDBMS you're using.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "unique rank".  Something like this probably does what you want:

```
CREATE VIEW `time_all` AS
    SELECT s.`datetime,
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `time_clock`.`scans` s2 WHERE s2.datetime <= s.datetime) as rank
    FROM `time_clock`.`scans` s
    ORDER BY `scans`.`datetime` ASC;
```

MySQL supports neither window functions nor CTEs.  Nor does it support variables in views.  A correlated subquery is one of the few ways of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this method

```
  delimiter $$
    DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `getRank`$$
    CREATE FUNCTION `getRank`() RETURNS int(11)
        DETERMINISTIC
    begin
    return if(@rankId, @rankId:=@rankId+1, @rankId:=1);
    end$$
```

Now if I want to use the function I created, just use it like this

```
CREATE VIEW time_all AS
SELECT getRank() AS 'rank', `scans`.`datetime` FROM `time_clock.scans`
ORDER BY scans.datetime ASC;
```