# How to Add Serial No in Select Statement in Mysql Join

Tags: mysql, sql, select

There is two table in database.

```
== tblOrder ==
OrderId
Customer
```

```
== tblOrderItem ==
OrderItemId
OrderId
ItemId
Qty
Price
```

My Query :-

```
SELECT o.OrderId,o.Customer,oi.ItemId,oi.Qty,oi.Price 
FROM tblorder o
JOIN tblorderitem oi ON oi.OrderId=o.OrderId
```

Result :-

```
+---------+----------+--------+-----+-------+
| OrderId | Customer | ItemId | Qty | Price |
+---------+----------+--------+-----+-------+
|    1001 | john day |    501 |   1 |    10 |
|    1001 | john day |    502 |   2 |     9 |
|    1002 | amy gill |    201 |   5 |     2 |
|    1003 | hardcaur |    501 |   1 |    10 |
|    1003 | hardcaur |    509 |   2 |     5 |
|    1003 | hardcaur |    201 |   2 |     2 |
+---------+----------+--------+-----+-------+
```

I want to generate SNO and SNOI(Temp Serial No) in select statement so that result will be like this :-

```
+------+---------+----------+------+--------+-----+-------+
| SNO  | OrderId | Customer | SNOI | ItemId | Qty | Price |
+------+---------+----------+------+--------+-----+-------+
|    1 |    1001 | john day |    1 |    501 |   1 |    10 |
|    1 |    1001 | john day |    2 |    502 |   2 |     9 |
|    2 |    1002 | amy gill |    1 |    201 |   5 |     2 |
|    3 |    1003 | hardcaur |    1 |    501 |   1 |    10 |
|    3 |    1003 | hardcaur |    2 |    509 |   2 |     5 |
|    3 |    1003 | hardcaur |    3 |    201 |   2 |     2 |
```

What will be my query?

Comment: you mean row number? Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Get row number on select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select)

Comment: There are two columns in your example called `SrNo`.  The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: the second SrNo is not logical, i don't understand the question

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Presumably TblOrder has columns OrderId, Customer and tblOrderItem has ItemId, Qty, Price?

Comment: @SEarle1986 Yes

Comment: You need to post the schema of the two tables and the sample data in them. I have noticed since my original comment that tblorderItem also has a column OrderId.

Comment: @SEarle1986 I have updated the question

Comment: You still have't added the schema of the two tables tblOrder and tblOrderItem and what their data looks like. That's crucial information to be able to help

Comment: You can't have two columns with the same name, so let's call them SrNoOrder and SrNoItem. What you want is a cumulative count on distinct OrderId for SrNoOrder, and a cumulative count on ItemId within each OrderId for SrNoItem. Right?

Comment: And the data in the two tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use variables.

```
 set @ord ='';
 set @val1 =1;
 set @val2 =0;

select SR_No_1, OrderId, Customer, SR_No_2, ItemId, Qty, Price
from 
(
SELECT    t.*,
          @val1 := if(@ord=OrderId, @val1+1, 1) as SR_No_2,
          @val2 := if(@ord=OrderId,@val2, @val2+1) as SR_No_1,
          @ord := OrderId
FROM      table1 t
 ) t   
ORDER BY  orderId asc;
```

**Result:**

```
+---------+---------+----------+---------+--------+-----+-------+
| SR_No_1 | OrderId | Customer | SR_No_2 | ItemId | Qty | Price |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+--------+-----+-------+
|       1 |    1001 | john day |       1 |    501 |   1 |    10 |
|       1 |    1001 | john day |       2 |    502 |   2 |     9 |
|       2 |    1002 | amy gill |       1 |    201 |   5 |     2 |
|       3 |    1003 | hardcaur |       1 |    501 |   1 |    10 |
|       3 |    1003 | hardcaur |       2 |    509 |   2 |     5 |
|       3 |    1003 | hardcaur |       3 |    201 |   2 |     2 |
+---------+---------+----------+---------+--------+-----+-------+
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/DANU13350)**

*P.S. Kindly note that for demonstration purpose i have inserted data to one table. you can modify the query by introducing the `join` between 2 tables*