# mysql get row position of unique id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a `RANK` table like this

```
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| uid         | VARCHAR(50) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    |               |
| steps       | int(20) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and I want to sort steps by DESC and get row position of specific row using uid which is primary.

I can sort them by

`SELECT uid, steps FROM RANK ORDER BY steps DESC`

but I have no clue how I can get a row position of specific row using uid. I saw some threads on stackoverflow and tried it on our DB server but it didn't work out well. Is there any way to do this?

I tried:

```
SET @rank=0; 
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, steps, COUNT(*) as ordercount 
FROM RANK 
GROUP BY steps 
ORDER BY ordercount DESC;
```

but it doesn't get my any result

**with sequelizejs**

```
async function getUserData(uid) {
    var query = ""
    query += "SELECT rank, total_steps_value FROM ("
    query += "    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, user_id, total_steps_value"
    query += "    FROM RANK"
    query += "    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS var"
    query += "    ORDER BY total_steps_value DESC) AS x"
    query += `WHERE user_id = ${mysql.escape(uid)}`

    let res = await models.sequelize.query(query)
    console.log("RES", res)
}
```

I get this error

```
SequelizeDatabaseError: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'user_id = '10208360871964156'' at line 1
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520357/mysql-get-row-number-on-select for information on adding a row number to  your select statement.

Comment: @kainaw I already looked at the thread but couldn't figure out how i can apply those answers to this situation since column types are different :(

Comment: Why do you think the column types make a difference?

Comment: Show what you tried and we can help you fix it. We're not going to write it for you.

Comment: @Barmar I tried `SET @rank=0;
SELECT @rank:=@rank+1 AS rank, itemID, COUNT(*) as ordercount
  FROM orders
  GROUP BY itemID
  ORDER BY ordercount DESC;` and this one looks like it doesn't have any value I can put into, especially primary id to find the row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `COUNT(*)`, since you're not trying to rank by a count, you just want to rank by a column value.

```
SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, uid
FROM RANK
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS var
ORDER BY steps DESC
```

To get the rank of a specific `uid`, put this in a subquery.

```
SELECT rank FROM (
    SELECT @rank := @rank + 1 AS rank, uid
    FROM RANK
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rank := 0) AS var
    ORDER BY steps DESC) AS x
WHERE uid = '123545'
```

Comment: It did work but how could I get a rank of specific row by uid?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for update, but the rank value goes up so It gets messed up if I run more than one time. how can i avoid it?

Comment: Sounds like you're not setting `@rank` back to `0` each time. I've updated the answer to show how to do this in the query itself rather than as a separate query.

Comment: I get syntax error when I run this on server side with sequelize, I updated the question about it!

Comment: You need a space before `WHERE`. Your SQL looks like `AS xWHERE uid`

Comment: A simple `console.log(query)` would have shown that.

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the rank of a particular row using:

```
select count(*)
from rank r
where r.score >= (select r2.score from rank r2 where r2.uid = ?);
```

Comment: I just updated the question about sequelize syntax error, I'd be really appreciated if you answer this too!